# Is reading a "char" from memory faster than reading a "word"?

Tags: c++, memory-management

[The memory subsystem on a modern processor is restricted to accessing memory at the granularity and alignment of it's word size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381244/purpose-of-memory-alignment).

So can I assume that reading a char from memory should be as fast as reading a word (4 bytes)?

If the answer is YES than why do we even use `char` variables when coding instead of `word` variables (Other than the obvious type checking necessity).

Comment: While it's been a long time since I had to worry about this level of optimization... its an interesting question nonetheless +1

Comment: A processor will normally read an entire cache line from memory at a time. It would waste a *lot* of memory to allocate a full cache line if you only really needed to store one byte though. It would also (often) cause a substantial slow-down, because it would reduce the effective cache size to only one char per line. Packing the data makes the cache more effective.

Comment: But regardless I will put in that cash line either a char or a word, so the scan would have to be done either way, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do we use `char` variables? To avoid wasting memory. If you need 4 variables, you can fit 4 `char`s in a single word, but if you declared them as `int` it would take 4 words.  If they only need to hold low numbers, all that extra memory is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

One reason I can immediately think of is that we just want a byte for an ASCII character.

```
const WORD* str = W"Hello World?";
               // ^ Some theoretical WORD-charactered string
```

Hehe.

And so because each character is just one byte, the processor would just have to do one fetch when getting, say, 4 characters.