# Java hashmap default size

Tags: java

Hi I have a situation where I have to store a single key value pair to my Hashmap . The map size is always constant. i.e., 1 . But default size of hash map is 16 bits . Here am almost wasting nearly 15 bits.  Is there any  way to limit the size of the hashmap.

Thanks in Advance for your valuable suggestions .

Comment: It's not 16 *bits* - it's 16 *entries*.

Comment: Why would someone use a `Hashmap` only for one key/value pair?

Comment: This is a prime example of a problem not being a problem unless you make it a problem. If you don't apply the word "waste", there is no problem here. More space is reserved than you use. So what? That happens under the hood whether you like it or not; research "memory alignment". Even if you use only 1 byte of memory, likely 8 bytes are actually used up in the process depending on the CPU architecture. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381244/purpose-of-memory-alignment

Comment: Now that you've accepted a different answer, it sounds like you didn't need a map to start with. In future, please be clearer about what you *actually* need - I answered the question you asked, but it appears that's not what you actually needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need a pair of immutable values, you can use `Pair` class.

[Pair Class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html)

You always can keep the  structure with this class, just use getLeft() for getting the key, and getRight() to return the value of your object.

Answer (score 11):

You can provide an initial capacity in the `HashMap` constructor:

```
Map<String> map = new HashMap<>(1);
```

It *looks* like that is genuinely obeyed in the implementation I'm looking at, but I can easily imagine some implementations having a "minimum viable capacity" such as 16. You'd have to be creating a large number of maps for this to really be an issue.

On the other hand, if you *really* only need a single-entry map and you're in a performance-sensitive situation, I would suggest you might not want to use `HashMap` at all. It wouldn't be hard to write a `Map` implementation which knew that it always had exactly one entry (which would presumably be provided on construction). If your code depends on having a `HashMap` rather than a `Map`, you should check whether you *really* want that top be the case.

Comment: Does this add a little boost to performance in term of memory?

Comment: @shareef: Well it reduces how much memory is required, which potentially the frequency of garbage collection, but I'd be surprised to see it be measurable.