# Why does compiler align N byte data types on N byte boundaries?

Tags: c, memory, compiler-construction, memory-alignment

I don't understand why the compiler aligns int on 4 byte boundaries, short on 2 byte boundaries and char on 1 byte boundaries.
I understand that the if the data bus width of the processor is 4 bytes, it takes 2 memory read cycles for reading an int from an address not a multiple of 4.
So, why doesn't the compiler align all data on 4 byte boundaries? 
For eg.:

```
struct s {
 char c;
 short s;
};
```

Here, 
1) why does the compiler align short on a 2 byte boundary? Assuming that the processor can fetch 4 bytes on a single memory read cycle, wouldn't it take only 1 memory read cycle to read short in the above case even if there is no padding between char and short?

2) Why doesn't the compiler align short on a 4 byte boundary?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Purpose of memory alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381244/purpose-of-memory-alignment)

Comment: the purpose of structure padding for alignment is to fetch the data in one machine read. In your case, the struct will be 4 and not 8. You can still fetch the char OR short in one cycle bu using masking. So while fetching the char the processor will fetch 4 bytes and mask out 24 bits.<br>
However, if you had something like this:<br>
`struct s { char c; int i};` then the size would get 8 byte coz you need full 4 bytes for the integer to be fetched in read cycle.

Comment: @NikhilVidhani: My question is not regarding the purpose of padding.  My question is about why the byte is padded between char and short and not after short.  Assuming the processor can fetch 4 bytes in a single cycle, no matter where the padding happens, the short can be fetched in 1 cycle, right? So, what's the savings that we get in the above case? I guess there is some hardware level explanation for this.

Comment: @linuxfreak going by my instincts... i think it is easier to fetch (mask) last 16 bits than the bits 9-24 if short were to occupy byte 2 and 3.

Comment: @NikhilVidhani - Yeah.. I think so.  To fetch the bits 9-24, the processor has to do bit shifting in addition to masking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my question.
There might be two reasons for why the byte is padded between char and short and not after short.

1) Some architectures might have 2 byte instructions that fetch only 2 bytes from the memory.  If such is the case, 2 memory read cycles are required to fetch the short.

2) Some architecture might not have 2 byte instructions.  Even in that case, the processor fetches the 4 bytes from memory to the register and masks the unrequired bytes to get the short value.  If the byte is not padded between char and short, the processor has to shift the bytes in order to get the short value.

Both the above cases might result in slower performance.  That is why the byte short is 2 byte aligned.

Comment: You forgot one important case: there are architectures that do not even *allow* a misaligned value to be read. In this case the compiler would have to emit two memory loads instead of one plus a number of bit manipulation instructions to fetch the value, and it would have to do similar stuff on writing. The later is even more problematic because the program cannot be allowed to invent writes to neighboring data (due to multithreading), so the compiler would have to fall back to writing the value byte by byte. It's obvious that it's better to forbid the existence of these pits in the language.

Answer (score 4):

These objects have to fit in arrays. An array is contiguous. Thus, if the first element is N byte aligned, and all objects are N bytes big, then necessarily all objects in the array are N byte aligned too.

So, if `short` would be 2 bytes big, but 4 bytes aligned, there would be 2 byte holes between all shorts in an array which is forbidden.

You do see that your assumption is slightly flawed. I could make a `struct` with 26 chars, and it wouldn't be 26 byte aligned. It could start anywhere. An N byte type with have an alignment equal to N **or dividing N**.

Comment: @iccthedral: definitely not. A 26 byte type might be 2 byte aligned, but not 52 byte aligned.

Comment: Why is short 2 byte aligned? Irrespective of whether a padding byte is added between char and short in the above structure, cpu requires only 1 memory read cycle.  So, why is there a byte padded between char and short? In other words, the alignment of the above structure is anyway 4, why not place the short below char without leaving a byte for padding?

Comment: I think it does so because the order in a data layout matters. And it wants to keep them naturally aligned.

Comment: @linuxfreak: If you use a 4 byte read, the short will be read into the same register as the `char` before it and the padding. Thus you probably need two extra instructions to remove the bits you don't want. By using a 16 bit read instead (which is commonly available) you get just the 16 bits you want, but that 16 bit read has to be aligned.

Comment: @MSalters When you say 52 byte aligned, what exactly do you mean? I meant that the address of it has to be multiple of some N.

Comment: @iccthedral: We might be getting confused by "N". I used N as the size of the type, not its alignment. A type with size S and alignment A must have A divide S, i.o.w. there's an integer C>=1 such that C*A = S.

Comment: Ah, okay, sorry for dicking. Just wanted to be sure what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

First, your premise is incorrect. Every object is aligned at some fundamental alignment. For some scalar objects, the alignment may be the same as the data size of the object, but it might also be smaller or larger. For example, a classic 32-bit architecture (I'm thinking of i386 here) might include both 8-byte doubles and 10-byte long doubles, both with 4-byte alignment. Note that I said *data size* above; do not confuse this with `sizeof`.

The actual size of an object may be larger than the data size, because the size of an object must be a multiple of the object's alignment. The reason is that an object's alignment is always the same, regardless of context. In other words, the alignment of an object *only depends on the type of the object*.

Consequently, in the structures:

```
struct example1 {
  type1 a;
  type2 b;
};

struct example2 {
  type2 b;
  type1 a;
};
```

the alignment of both b's is the same. In order to be able to guarantee this alignment, it is necessary that the alignment of a composite type must be the maximum of the alignments of the member types. That means that `struct example1` and `struct example2` above have the same alignment.

The requirement that the alignment of an object be dependent only on its type implies that the size of a type must be a multiple of its alignment. (Any type can be the element type of an array, including an array of only one element. The size of the array is the product of the size of the element and the number of elements. So any padding necessary must be part of the size of the element.)

In general, rearranging members in a composite type might change the composite type's size but it cannot change the composite type's alignment. For example, both of the following structs have the same alignment -- which is the alignment of a `double` -- but the first one is almost certainly smaller:

```
struct compact {
  double d;   // Must be at offset 0
  char   c1;  // Will be at offset sizeof(double)
  char   c2;  // Will be at offset sizeof(double)+sizeof(char).
};

struct bloated {
  char   c1;  // Must be at offset 0
  double d;   // Will be at offset alignof(double)
  char   c2;  // Will be at offset (alignof(double) + sizeof(double))
};
```

Comment: I think this doesn't answer my question.  I'm asking about the h/w level explanation for padding bytes.  In the case of short, the padding byte is added between the char and the short.  Why not add the padding byte after short? Both the cases require only 1 memory cycle read, right? (assuming the processor can fetch 4 bytes in 1 cycle)

Comment: @linuxfreak: There may not be a hardware need in that case. But there is a software need, and that's what I'm explaining. C requires that the alignment of a type be consistent, and if sometimes the short must be 2-byte aligned (for example, so that it doesn't cross between cache-lines) then it *always* must be 2-byte aligned. If you didn't understand that from the answer, let me know and I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler align data as prescribed by the target processor [(micro-)architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microarchitecture) and the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). Look for instance into the [x86-64 ABI spec](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf) as an example.

<sup>If your compiler aligned differently than what some ABI specifies, you won't be able to call functions from libraries respecting that ABI!</sup>

In your example, if (on x86-64) the short field `s` was not aligned on 2 bytes, the processor would have to work more (perhaps issuing two accesses) to get that field.

Also, on many x86-64 chips, the cache line is often some multiple of 16 (or maybe less) bytes. So it makes sense to align a [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) frame on 16 bytes. And this is needed for vector-like local variables (AVX, SSE3, etc...)

On some processors, having badly aligned data would either give a fault (e.g. [interrupt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) for a machine exception) or slow down the processing significantly. In addition, it could render some accesses non-atomic (for multi-core processing). Hence some ABIs prescribe more ABI that what is strictly necessary. Also, some recent features of CPUs (like [vectorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28parallel_computing%29), e.g. thru [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) instructions like [AVX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) or [SSE3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE3)) do benefit from very aligned data (e.g. alignment to 16 bytes). Your compiler might optimize more -to use such instructions- if it know about such a strong alignment.

Comment: On all Core2 based processors a cache line is 64 bytes not 16 bytes. The call stack is aligned to 16 bytes for 64-bit code. For 32-bit code it's not necessarily aligned to 16 bytes.

Comment: Sorry...I missed the word MULTIPLE in "multiple of 16 bytes". For core2 that multiple is 4. Maybe on Pentium4 it was 2 (32 bytes)? Was it only 16 bytes at some point (e.g. before Pentium4)? Is this the real reason the call stack is a multiple of 16 bytes?