# __attribute__ packed of an integer

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, memory-alignment, packing

in the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) they give information on how integers can be **aligned**. Can the same thing be done for *packing* integers?

For example, is this valid on a system that doesn't do automatically handle improperly aligned data?

```
typedef uint16_t __attribute__ ((packed)) packed_uint16_t;
```

On my system it gives:

> align.c:7:1: warning: ‘packed’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
>
> typedef uint16_t **attribute** ((packed)) packed_uint16_t;

But my system properly handles unaligned bytes, so I guess it would ignore it then!

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688715/byte-alignment-for-integer-or-other-types-in-a-uint8-t-array?noredirect=1#comment47517574_29688715)

Comment: I don't know what it would even mean to pack a `uintN_t`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__attribute__((packed))` only pertains structures. It specifies that there shall be no padding between or after structure members. The compiler still assumes that the structure itself is aligned correctly but it might generate special code to access the misaligned structure members.

If you have a misaligned pointer (I'm not sure how you get such a pointer any way) and you want to portably dereference it, consider doing something like this:

```
some_type *mptr;                     /* misaligned pointer */
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof *mptr); /* get some aligned memory */
memcpy(buffer, mptr, sizeof *mptr);
some_type *aptr = (some_type*)mptr;  /* pointer to aligned data */
```

Comment: so in other words there is no way to do this in one line. Well drat -- thanks anyway!

Btw, I get misaligned data because I am designing a memory manager for microcontrollers and I would like it to all be packed!

Comment: @GarrettLinux No! Please don't There is a reason this alignment stuff exists. Just figure out what the maximum alignment requirement for that controller is and align the buffers you return to that. It's probably 2 or 4, so you're wasting 3 bytes per allocation at most. Seriously, it's not worth the effort especially considering that your code is going to slow down considerably.

Comment: Haha, well if you insist :)  I will definitely add the option so the user can do whatever they want -- but you are probably right. On truly constrained systems (16bit) I assume the alignment would be only 2 bytes.

Comment: btw, is `#define WORD_SIZE = sizeof(int)` always going to work? If not, is there a standard, cross platform way to find this?

Comment: @GarettLinux what does “word size” mean for you? If you mean “alignment requirement of the type with the largest alignment requirement,” then with C11 you can use `_Alignof(max_align_t)`. The type `max_align_t` is defined in `stddef.h`.