# Arrays in c shared library

Tags: c, arrays, shared-libraries

I want to basically process a struct array in a method in a dynamic library, but when I pass the array and print it (in the exact same manner as in my main program) it has different values.

Consider a struct like this:

```
struct color {
    uint8_t b;
    uint8_t g;
    uint8_t r;
    uint8_t a;
}
```

And the code to print it looks like this:

```
printf("pos: %p\n", array);
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("bgra: %08x\n", ((uint32_t *) array)[i]);
}
```

Now, what I'm doing in the test program is this:

```
printf("Table:\n");
print(table, size);
```

and the output looks like this (as excepted):

```
pos: 0x7fff5b359530
bgra: 00000000
bgra: ff0000ff
bgra: ff00ffff
```

But when i execute the same code in a function in the library this is what i get:

```
pos: 0x7fff5b359530
bgra: 00000008
bgra: 00000030
bgra: 5b3598e0
```

Now I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong, since i can't see a fault in my code. Also, the values must correlate somehow since, the output is always the same (Except for the address of course).

header.h

```
#include <stdint.h>

#ifndef __HEADER_H_
#define __HEADER_H_

struct bmpt_color_bgra {
    uint8_t b;
    uint8_t g;
    uint8_t r;
    uint8_t a;
};

void print(struct bmpt_color_bgra *table, uint8_t size);
uint8_t *gen(struct bmpt_color_bgra *table, uint8_t size);
#endif
```

library.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))

__attribute__((constructor))
static void initializer(void) {
    printf("[%s] initializer()\n", __FILE__);
}

__attribute__((destructor))
static void finalizer(void) {
    printf("[%s] finalizer()\n", __FILE__);
}

EXPORT
void print(struct bmpt_color_bgra *table, uint8_t size) {
    uint8_t i;

    printf("pos: %p\n", table);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("bgra: %08x\n", ((uint32_t *) table)[i]);
    }
}

EXPORT
uint8_t *gen(struct bmpt_color_bgra *table, uint8_t size) {
    printf("table in func:\n");
    print(table, size);
}
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct bmpt_color_bgra arr[3];
    struct bmpt_color_bgra c;

    c.b = 0x0;
    c.g = 0x0;
    c.r = 0x0;
    c.a = 0x0;
    arr[0] = c;

    c.b = 0xff;
    c.a = 0xff;
    arr[1] = c;

    c.r = 0xff;
    arr[2] = c;

    //the first result (the correct one)
    print(arr, 3);

    //the second result
    gen(arr, 3);
}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Did you notice that the data `bgra: 5b3598e0` has some numerals in common with the address `pos: 0x7fff5b359530`?

Comment: Can you show the signature of the print() function.

Comment: Unit now I didn't, could that be because of the cast of the array?

Comment: In `printf("pos: %p\n", table);` you are supposed to `printf("pos: %p\n", (void*)table);` don't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: @LPs all three elements of `arr[3]` are initialised from `c` as in `arr[0] = c;` etc.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't think that would make any difference, since first of all, the problem doesn't lie with the pointer (I think?) since those are the same.

Comment: @redxef it might make a difference to what is pushed onto stack. I suggest correcting it anyway.

Comment: @WeatherVane General rule, not to this specific case. BTW I wrote it badly, it is `struct bmpt_color_bgra arr[3] = {{0}};`

Comment: @redxef can u print the position pointed by `((uint32_t *) array)` as well?

Comment: @saby the result of the `(int32_t *)` is the same as the `(void *)` address.

Comment: @redxef so de-referencing the address is the issue? Is that even possible?

Comment: How is the library generated?

Comment: @saby that is why I'm so confused, by now I am considering another compiler and system.

Comment: @LPs I'm using an automatically generated makefile in NetBeans with the C Plugin installed.

Comment: Is that you real code? Are you sure your system is clean, I mean: no other previously version of library installed somewhere on the system with a bug?.

Comment: The two types are not compatible, therefore the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @LPs I didn't use any libraries in this build, this is all my own code and the example code is exactly this way (ok, I have changed the names for simplicity but other than that...)

Comment: @2501 The same problem arises when I access every field of the struct and print it.

Comment: Then the question should be closed as you're not showing the actual code you're using. Who knows what is really in there.

Comment: With the relevant code copied into a simple one-module source file (ignoring the constructor etc), it works properly, that is the second function gives the same output from the first function as when the first function is called directly.

Comment: `test.c` includes a header `bmptool.h`, which appears to be the only possible source for a declaration of type `struct bmpt_color_bgra` and of functions `gen()` and `print()`.  You do not provide that header, and `library.c` uses a different one.  This opens up the possibility that declarations do not match.

Comment: @WeatherVane was faster, but see it [on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/WSRsOL)

Comment: @JohnBollinger My bad, that one should also be named `header.h`

Comment: I built a shared library from your `library.c`, and I built a program from your `test.c` that dynamically links the library.  The resulting dynamically-linked executable produces the expected output.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Interesting, what compiler did you use?

Comment: I tried to manually compile it, which worked... turns out it was the IDE?

Comment: The only plausible explanation I see is that either your function declarations or your `struct` declaration is being interpreted differently in the separate compilations of your modules.  This could arise from different compilation options.

Comment: Note that function `print()`'s cast from `struct bmpt_color_bgra *` to `uint32_t *` is suspicious, and a possible source of error.  At best, it violates the strict-aliasing rule.  At worst, it is simply wrong, because there can be padding between members of the struct that would cause its representation to differ from what you assume it will be.

Comment: Well could someone close the question since it probably falls under the category "stupid programmer", "wrong compiler options" or something along the lines, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This probably comes down to memory alignment of the members within the struct, and the size of the struct itself differing between your program and the dynamic/shared library.  You don't mention which compiler you are using, but using different compiler(s) or compiler options for your program and the shared library could cause this effect.

You can preserve binary compatibility between modules by specifying exactly how the members of the struct should be aligned.  E.g in GCC you can force how the struct is represented in memory by use of an attribute.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html for GCC alignment instructions

```
struct bmpt_color_bgra {
    uint8_t b;
    uint8_t g;
    uint8_t r;
    uint8_t a;
} __attribute__ ((packed));
```

Also take a look at [Byte Alignment for integer (or other) types in a uint8_t array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688715/byte-alignment-for-integer-or-other-types-in-a-uint8-t-array) for a similar question.