# Are structs guaranteed to be aligned to sizeof(size_t) in C?

Tags: c

I have the following struct:

```
struct data {
        char buffer[12];
        bool flag;
}
```

When testing the size of the `data` structure, I realized it was `16` bytes because of the boolean flag which added `3` bytes in padding. So I decided to do the following while using the last byte of the `buffer` as the flag:

```
struct data {
        char buffer[16];
}
```

This way my `buffer` is `3` bytes larger for free as it would have been lost in padding anyway.

However, I want this structure to be platform independent, so I looked on cppreference and [found the following](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object) (emphasis mine):

> Every complete object type has a property called alignment requirement, **which is an integer value of type size_t representing the number of bytes between successive addresses** at which objects of this type can be allocated.

Based off this, I wrote the following:

```
struct data {
        char buffer[12 + sizeof(size_t)];
}
```

It works on my device, but I am just wondering if this is guaranteed to properly align on all platforms and not waste any bytes?

**Edit:** I am aware that `sizeof(size_t)` may be `8` bytes, making my structure `20` bytes. However, if the alignment is by `8` bytes, then my structure would be `20` bytes regardless. This is why I wish to know how the structure is aligned.

Comment: I would say, don't bother. Having the boolean flag as an element in the array makes no sense from a design perspective. Or from a perspective of *readable* and *understandable* and *maintainable* code either. And premature optimizations are usually bad. And the compiler will make sure that the structure object are aligned nicely anyway. The only time you need to worry about these things is if you have nanosecond timing requirements, or extremely hard memory limits.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am aware the compiler will align the struct regardless, but the extra buffer size would be nice.

Comment: See 6.2.8 Alignment of objects

Comment: By the way, `sizeof(size_t)` might actually be *eight* bytes, making your structure 20 bytes large.

Comment: let me understand this, are you trying to make the buffer bigger or are you trying to pack the structure?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am aware of this. If the alignment was `8` bytes, then the structure would also be `20` bytes large. This is why I am asking the question.

Comment: @AhmedMasud Make the buffer larger.

Comment: If you don't want to have wasted space, why not do `struct data {
        char buffer[15];
        char flag;
}` or something like that?

Comment: @SteveSummit That is assuming the alignment is four bytes.

Comment: Just use `struct data {
        char buffer[12];
        bool flag;
}`.  The padding code sees in one case, may not be there (zero) on another compiler.

Comment: @SteveSummit it is not the solution as your char might be aligned or even if the structure is packed the next object will be aligned just leaving the unused gap between this potentially packed structure and that object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Structure alignment padding, largest size of padding, and order of struct members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360612/structure-alignment-padding-largest-size-of-padding-and-order-of-struct-member)

Comment: @AhmedMasud This does not answer my question.

Comment: @MichaelSmith Oh you want a answer ? "no".

Comment: BTW `sizeof(bool)` might not be 1.

Comment: @MichaelSmith it is platform and the implementation dependent. Some hardware does not allow unaligned access, some compilers have additional mechanisms helping aligning and organizing the members of the structs. If the code is going to be 100% portable it is not possible.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 But the standard specifies that every object type has the property `alignment requirement`. I do not understand how it isn't portable based off the quote from cppreference.

Comment: @MichaelSmith With your compiler, what is the size of `struct one { char c; }`?

Comment: @chux It is `1`. But I thought that `sizeof(char)` is by definition `1` in all compilers?

Comment: @MichaelSmith The point is that is the basis to  a counter example to the title question.

Comment: @chux Oh I thought you meant size of the member itself, the struct itself is `4` bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are `struct`s guaranteed to be aligned to `sizeof(size_t)` in C?

No.

---

I suspect the following will meet OP's goal of getting access to the padding.  Member order is important.  Put smallest members last. `char` is always smallest.

```
struct data_ref {
  bool flag;
  char buffer[12];
};

#define PAD (sizeof(struct data_ref) - sizeof(char)*12 - sizeof(bool))

struct data {
  bool flag;
  char buffer[12 + PAD];
};
```

Comment: @Stargateur How would you suggest to use `offsetof` here?

Comment: it does not save any bytes it only makes sizeof struct smaller. And it is the truth if it the only one object. Otherwise it will add the padding after your structure.

Comment: that is a good question... never mind ! I uncomfortable with your example but... yeah something wrong but I don't know what.

Comment: @Stargateur Perhaps `#define PAD (sizeof(struct data_ref) - offsetof(data_ref, buffer)/*the last member*/ - sizeof(char)*12)`?  This answer does not yet well handle a  more complex `struct` with many members, yet your offset idea helps find the padding from the last member to the end.

Answer (score 1):

> Are structs guaranteed to be aligned to sizeof(size_t) in C?

No. Why would they be?

Comment: I only thought this because of the quote I provided from cppreference. They state that all objects have a property of `alignment requirement`.

Comment: @MichaelSmith Yes, all objects have an alignment requirement. What does that have to do with `sizeof (size_t)`?

Comment: I think your answer is too long. "no" was enough.

Comment: @melpomene From the quote I provided: `which is an integer value of type size_t representing the number of bytes between successive addresses`. I am not sure if I misunderstood, but it seems they are saying the alignment is of type `size_t`.

Comment: @MichaelSmith Yes, the alignment is of type `size_t`. E.g. `char` is an object type whose alignment requirement is `(size_t)1`. What does the type of the number have to do with its value?

Comment: @melpomene Thanks, I misunderstood the type of the address for the actual size of the alignment.

Comment: @MichaelSmith you misunderstood it again.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 How so?

Comment: @MichaelSmith do not take it personally - but I think it is too early for you for this topic. You should just trust us and remember that your solution will not save you any bytes.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 `your solution will not save you any bytes` Is that so? The accepted answer directly contradicts that.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard does not dictate the alignment of fields within a `struct`.  Section 6.7.2.1 p14 of the [C standard states](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> Each non-bit-field member of a structure or union object is aligned in
>   an implementation-defined manner appropriate to its type.

So there's no guarantee that a given struct will be laid out the same way on two different compilations of the same source code, whether that be different compilers or the same compiler with different optimizations settings.

As a counterexample, given the following struct:

```
struct test1 {
    char s[13];
};
```

On my machine, `sizeof(struct test1)` evaluated to 13 and `_Alignof(struct test1)` evaluates to 1.  In fact, I get the same result with your first definition of `struct data`, indicating that there's no padding.

So there is no guarantee that structs are aligned on a `sizeof(size_t)` boundary.

Regarding the quote you gave:

> Every complete object type has a property called alignment
>   requirement, which is an integer value of type size_t representing the
>   number of bytes between successive addresses at which objects of this
>   type can be allocated.

This states that all types have an *alignment requirement*, and that *that value* has a type of `size_t`, not that a type has to have an alignment of that `sizeof(size_t)`.

That being said, there is a way that structs *tend to be laid out*, and you can typically reduce the size of the struct if you follow these conventions.

Generally speaking, the alignment requirement of a struct ends up being the largest alignment requirement of its fields, and the alignment requirement of an array is the same as that of its containing type.  Also, a primitive type `n` bytes in size typically needs to be aligned on an `n` byte boundary.  So when you have fields within a struct with different alignment requirements, padding will typically be inserted to ensure each field's alignment requirement is satisfied.

In the case of your structure, you have a `char` array whose element size is 1 and a `bool` whose size (on my machine at least) is also 1, so the struct as a whole has an alignment requirement of 1 and no padding is needed.

Making use of these properties, you can usually reduce the size of your structs.  [The Lost Art of Struct Packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing) goes into this in much more detail.

To reiterate however, the way fields in a struct are laid out is **implementation defined** according to the standard.  So while you *might* be able to lay out your struct to minimize padding, there is still no guarantee that it will always be the same in all environments.

Comment: just for this amazing link of The Lost Art of C Structure Packing, I need to be able to upvote more than one time ;)

Answer (score 0):

> **Are structs guaranteed to be aligned to sizeof(size_t) in C?**

No.

You've misunderstood the use of `size_t` in the quoted paragraph. The alignment of a type is a value *of type* `size_t`. For example, the alignment of type `char` is `(size_t)1`, and a structure containing only a single `char` member might itself have an alignment of `(size_t)1`. (Or it might have a larger alignment.)

`size_t` is just the type used to represent an alignment value. The size or alignment of the type `size_t` has nothing to do with the size or alignment of a structure -- unless the structure happens to have a member of type `size_t`.

Answer (score -3):

`struct`'s required alignment is measured by the biggest alignment of any of it's members.

i.e., a `struct` with only `char` types will be aligned on a `char` alignment (single byte for the most part).

a struct that contains an `int` (and sometimes `bool` is implemented using an `int`) will be aligned on an `int` alignment as well as include any required padding for the `int` in the struct to be aligned.

The logic behind this alignment scheme is for `struct` arrays.

i.e.:

```
/* assuming int requires a 4 byte boundary alignment */
struct example_s {
  char bytes[2];
  /* char padding[2]; //  2 byte padding so `int` is aligned */
  int i;
};

struct example_s example_array[10];
```

This will promise that the `example_array[2].i` is properly aligned.

Comment: If you're going to down vote - at least let me know why and what to fix.

Comment: all your answer is false according to the C standard.

Comment: @Stargateur - How so? my answer explains the struct alignment requirement according to the standard. What's false about it?

Comment: I didn't vote on your answer but it makes quite a strong claim without backing it up. Do you have any references to the standard to support it?

Comment: @melpomene - there's a quote in the question that said pretty much the same thing (only it was misinterpreted by OP), it's generally referring to section 6.2.8 in the standard.

Comment: Wrong: but the alignment of the `struct` is probably the same as the maximal *alignment* (not size!) of members

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - Cool, I'll fix that. However, it's worth pointing out that the size of the type and it's alignment requirement will calculate to the same number of bytes in all cases (except for bit fields).

Comment: Wrong: `alignof(char[15])` is 1, but `sizeof(char[15])` is 15

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The original answer referred to "size of type" not "size of member" - i.e. `sizeof (char), not `char a[15]; sizeof(a)`... but I can see where I might have been misunderstood. The updated answer is probably clearer,

Comment: Again `sizeof` and `alignof` are different

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - where do you see `sizeof` in my answer?