# C/C++: How can a structure contain a pointer pointing to itself?

Tags: c++, c

The question is more of theory-based than practical implementation.

What I would like to know is, in the code:

```
struct temp {
    int num;
    struct temp *next;
};
```

In the structure made above, how does the compiler decide how much of space should be allocated in memory when we instantiate it?

If I try to dry-run the code, the size of an integer would be 2 or 4 bytes, after that, if I try to find the size of the pointer to the structure itself, I enter a structure containing another integer and a pointer to itself.

By this logic, the compiler would enter an infinite loop when deciding to allocate space to an element of this structure, how then is the space decided?

P.S. I did try to find out the size of this structure myself (using the `sizeof()` operator, it turned out to be 16 bytes (the size of the integer being 4 bytes)... I'm interested in knowing how did it determine this figure of 16 bytes as the space required!

Comment: A pointer's size doesn't depend on the type of object it points to. The situation you describe is something like `struct temp { int num; struct temp next; };` which is, as you explain, not possible to resolve.

Comment: The memory has to be allocated at runtime. The compiler doesn't need to know the structure's size to allocate a pointer.

Comment: `sizeof` is not a function.

Comment: 16 bytes: 4 for the `int` and probably 8 for the pointer. the extra 4 are padding for [alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381244/purpose-of-memory-alignment).

Comment: The size of a pointer to some type T and the size of T are unrelated.

Comment: The __this__ keyword is gonna blow your mind...

Comment: [`this` is what you want. `this` is what you get.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0bk6Hbz0ZU)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the structure made above, how does the compiler decide how much of space should be allocated in memory when we instantiate it?

Pointer types take up a fixed size, which is not dependent on the pointed-to type (IOW, the size and representation of `struct temp *` is not in any way dependent on the size or representation of `struct temp`).  Furthermore, all pointer to `struct` types have the same size:

> **6.2.5 Types**
> ...
> 28 A pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
> pointer to a character type.<sup>48)</sup> Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of
> compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. ***All
> pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements
> as each other.*** All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and
> alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same
> representation or alignment requirements.

<sup>*[C 2011 online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

On platforms like x86, *all* pointer types have the same size and representation, but the standard has to take oddball architectures into account.

It's no different than if you had a pointer to `int` or pointer to `void` as a member.  The only thing that makes it look weird is that you're creating a self-referential pointer, which is allowed:

> **6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers**
> ...
> 3 A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type (***hence,
> a structure shall not contain an instance of itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance
> of itself***), except that the last member of a structure with more than one named member
> may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union containing, possibly
> recursively, a member that is such a structure) shall not be a member of a structure or an
> element of an array.

<sup>*ibid.*</sup>

Even though the struct type itself is not complete until the closing `}` of the definition, any *pointer* to it is complete (that is, its size is known).

The size of the pointed-to type matters for pointer arithmetic (i.e., the address value resulting from `p + 1` will depend on the size of the thing `p` points to).  However, it doesn't matter for storing the pointer itself.

Answer (score 6):

A structure containing a pointer to itself is not a problem.

A pointer has a fixed size, so it doesn't matter how big the size of the structure it points to is.  On most systems you're likely to come across, a pointer will be either 4 bytes or 8 bytes in size.

For the `struct` you've given, the `int` field will probably use 4 bytes and the `struct temp *` field will probably use 8 bytes.  This means the struct will be at least 12 bytes in size, probably 16 due to padding for proper alignment.

If on the other hand you had something like this:

```
struct temp {
    int num;
    struct temp next;
};
```

This would not be legal because the struct contains a *copy* of itself, which would in turn contain a copy of itself, and so on.