# Does VC++ support _mm_malloc?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, memory-alignment

Does Visual Studio C++ 2008/2010 support `_mm_malloc` officially? It is defined in `malloc.h` but I can't find its description in the MSDN library.

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't answer your question directly, but I think you're suppose to use [`_aligned_malloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6%28VS.80%29.aspx). If my understanding is correct, `_mm_malloc` is for Intel compilers.

Comment: `_mm_malloc` is supported by gcc, and `_aligned_malloc` is not. Microsoft compiler seems to be support it too, but I can't find any official paper about it.

Comment: It's seems to not be officially supported, the msvc "implementation" is just `#define _mm_malloc(a, b)    _aligned_malloc(a, b)` so it's pretty much just a matter of whether you want to rely on MS not changing that(a pretty good assumption is they'll keep that around), or provide a similar define when you're compiling for windows.

Comment: It should be noted that `_aligned_alloc` is **NOT** the C11/C++11 `aligned_alloc` : the parameters are inverted and `_aligned_alloc` is not compatible with `free`.

Answer (score 2):

`_mm_malloc/_mm_free` supported in Visual Studio 2013 with using the `<malloc.h>`  header.

Comment: "using the header" - which header?

Comment: @Robinson The one in the question: `<malloc.h>`

Answer (score 0):

See [Equivalent C code for _mm_ type functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552339/equivalent-c-code-for-mm-type-functions) and, more distantly related, [How to allocate aligned memory only using the standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227897/solve-the-memory-alignment-in-c-interview-question-that-stumped-me)

Comment: I know how to manually achieve alignment. The question wasn't about it. The first link has nothing to do with my question too.

Comment: I see - I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @EmeryBerger Thanks for the second link.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't memalign() in `<malloc.h>` solve this? The man-page says it's obsolete, but ...