# Cast void pointer to int

Tags: c++, visual-c++, casting, compiler-warnings

With a VC++ project I have a line:

```
FXint realIndex = (int)m_cmbDevice->getItemData(indx);
```

This reads a void pointer value from combo box to an int value. In VC++ it compiles and works well.
Now I have to port this to Linux and there I get a compile error

```
cpp:514:20: error: 
      cast from pointer to smaller type 'int' loses information
        FXint realIndex = (int)m_cmbDevice->getItemData(indx);
```

Now I use

```
std::size_t x = reinterpret_cast<std::size_t>(m_cmbDevice->getItemData(indx));
FXint realIndex = x;
```

My question is now, is this the right way to go?

Comment: Yeah, that won't lose any info. But if `sizeof(FXint) < sizeof(size_t)`, then you will lose info at that point instead (i.e., in the actual assignment).

Comment: Add a `static_assert(sizeof(FXint) == sizeof(void*), "Size of FXint doesn't match size of a pointer!");` before doing the cast, to make sure you won't lose any information

Comment: please show a [mre], what is returned by `m_cmbDevice->getItemData`?

Comment: A simple Static Cast should Work fine

Comment: @just a guy How can a staticcast looks like?

Comment: static_cast<int>(yourPointer) If you want to use it to save a pointer I would recommend using a unsigned long instead of an int

Answer (score 1):

- <s>`reinterpret_cast` is dangerous and is typically used only to interpret a pointer as another kind of pointer. You should use `static_cast` instead</s>
- `size_t` is not necessarily big enough to store a pointer. There are already [`intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35071200/995714) which are signed and unsigned integer types that are [*capable of holding a pointer*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)
- `FXint realIndex = x;` still raises a warning if `x` is wider than `FXint`, so another cast is necessary to turn off all related warnings

So you need to do this

```
auto x = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(m_cmbDevice->getItemData(indx));
auto realIndex = (FXint)x;
```

Comment: Also, casting to FXint with C-style cast is unsafe. That is where static_cast should have been used. Except, performing any cast is unsafe in the first place and the correct solution would be make sure that FXint is a sufficiently wide integer type.

Comment: This is very good but misses that one should `#include <cstdint>`, and that then only guarantees to declare these types within namespace `std::`, not the global namespace.