# Which cast to use when casting between pointers and intptr_t/uintptr_t?

Tags: c++, casting

1. When casting pointers to/from `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`, should you prefer either of `reinterpret_cast` or `std::bit_cast` over the other, and if so, **why** is one better than the other?
2. (How) does the answer change for function pointers vs. object pointers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a pointer into an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153065/converting-a-pointer-into-an-integer)

Comment: They should normally have the same effect, but nobody ever expects `bit_cast` to be used for this. Just use the normal C++ casts.

Comment: `bit_cast` can be used in `constexpr` contexts. I wonder what practical use-case would it have to convert between integer and pointer types; maybe some implementation of `offsetof` using back to back casts.

Comment: @Red.Wave See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071200/what-is-the-use-of-intptr-t

Comment: @Bob__ my concern is valid use-cases for `constexpr`contexts. Otherwise, allocator design is an area where none-consexpr casts are normally applied.

Comment: @mch: no, that question says nothing about `std::bit_cast`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. When casting pointers to/from `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`, should you prefer either of `reinterpret_cast` or `std::bit_cast` over the other, and if so, why is one better than the other?

I would prefer a `reinterpret_cast`, when possible, because:

1. It does not require C++20 and therefore is more portable across C++ versions, starting with C++03.
2. It does not require including a standard library header, which makes your code more lightweight. Although `<bit>` is not supposed to be particularly heavy by itself (for now, as of C++23), it may include other parts of the standard library internally and end up bringing a nontrivial amount of code into your compilation.

More on when one might still prefer `std::bit_cast` below.

> 2. (How) does the answer change for function pointers vs. object pointers?

The C++ standard refers to the C standard for the definition of `intptr_t`/`uintptr_t`, which says these are integral types (signed and unsigned, respectively) such that (C99, 7.18.1.4):

> any valid pointer to `void` can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to `void`, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer

By transition, this covers all pointers to objects, since any valid object pointer can be cast to `void*` and back without loss (C99, 6.3.2.3/1):

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any incomplete or object type. A pointer to any incomplete or object type may be converted to a pointer to `void` and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

Note that no such guarantee is given for function pointers. The C++ standard also does not provide any stronger guarantees - neither for function pointers, nor for pointers to members (see C++23, [conv.ptr], [conv.mem] and [conv.fctptr]).

So, to answer your question, in a conforming program `reinterpret_cast` cannot be used to convert between function pointers or pointers to members and `intptr_t`/`uintptr_t`. In practice, function pointers usually have the same size as object pointers, and you can cast them to `intptr_t`/`uintptr_t` and back without loss. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/WxqE1PKGj), for example. Pointers to members (whether member functions or member data) are usually larger than object pointers, which means you cannot cast them without loss.

[`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) works for any trivially copyable types (including function pointers and pointers to members), but it requires that the source and target types have the same size. Which means it will work for function pointers, as long as their size is the same as `intptr_t`/`uintptr_t`, but it will most likely fail for pointers to members. The benefit over `reinterpret_cast` here is that when `std::bit_cast` compiles, it works and it is required to work by the standard.

Comment: Thanks, seems like this covers everything. +1