# Using allocators to replace malloc()/free()?

Tags: c++, memory, malloc

Is there any portable way to replace usage of malloc()/free() with wrappers around STL-like allocators?

The context: I have a C library that allows to specify custom malloc()/free()-like functions for memory management, and which is used in multi-threaded contexts. Looking around for a good multi-threaded allocator, I've found that GCC-libstdc++'s mt_alloc performs very well for my workloads. Now I would like to use it in said C library, but how to do it?

The major problem I see is in the deallocate() function, which, contrary to free(), takes the size of the allocated memory block in addition to its address. So I need somehow to keep track of the size associated to every memory allocation, so that it can be fed back to deallocate() when freeing the memory. The simplest solution I've thought about to solve this is to store the size of the allocated memory at the beginning of the memory block, but then I'm not sure how to solve alignment issues that could arise.

Is there any simple solution that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Keep in mind that containers allocate memory in increasingly larger chunks, and hoards whatever memory it has when its size decreases. Your C library will probably not have the same usage pattern, so you might not even see the same performance improvement as with containers.

Comment: @Emile: what I was thinking to keep track of the size is to allocate extra space to store the size of the chunk _within_ the chunk. So, if n bytes are requested, allocate something like n + sizeof(std::size_t) (+- alignment considerations), and return the base address + sizeof(std::size_t). When freeing pointer p, take p - sizeof(std::size_t), read the size and pass it to deallocate().

Comment: Yeah, I somehow missed that when I read your question. Must be ADD. :-)

Comment: 3.11 [basic.align] (para 5 in n3242) Alignment: <quote>Alignments have an order from weaker to stronger or stricter alignments. Stricter alignments have larger alignment values. An address that satisfies an alignment requirement also satisfies any weaker valid alignment requirement.</quote> Thus if `alignof(std::size_t)` >= `alignof(<your Type>)` Then everything should be fine. Also note `alignof(std::max_align_t)` is probably the largest alignment (though implementations are free to have objects with `extended alignment` this is rare).

Comment: Note: if your compiler does not yet support `alignof` then try `__alignof`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my platform, `malloc` ensures that allocated memory is aligned at an 8-byte boundary. To mimic this behavior, use an `allocator<uint64_t>`:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ext/mt_allocator.h>

static __gnu_cxx::__mt_alloc<uint64_t> theAllocator;

void* mtmalloc(size_t size)
{
    // Divide size by sizeof(uint64_t) and round up
    size_t payloadElementCount = (size + sizeof(uint64_t) - 1) /
                                 sizeof(uint64_t);

    // Add an extra uint64_t to store the chunk size
    size_t chunkElementCount = 1 + payloadElementCount;

    // Allocate the chunk
    uint64_t* chunk = theAllocator.allocate(chunkElementCount);

    // Store the chunk size in the first word
    chunk[0] = chunkElementCount;

    // Return a pointer past where the chunk size is stored
    return static_cast<void*>(chunk + 1);
}

void mtfree(void* pointer)
{
    // The chunk begins one word before the passed in pointer
    uint64_t* chunk = static_cast<uint64_t*>(pointer) - 1;

    // Retrieve the chunk size
    size_t chunkElementCount = chunk[0];

    // Deallocate the chunk
    theAllocator.deallocate(chunk, chunkElementCount);
}

int main()
{
    int* array = (int*)mtmalloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
    array[0] = 0;
    array[1] = 1;
    array[2] = 2;
    array[3] = 3;
    mtfree(array);
}
```

For your platform, substitute `uint64_t` with the appropriate type.

You should test this with something like Valgrind to insure there are no memory leaks!

---

Instead of `uint64_t`, you can use GCC's `__BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__` and Boost's `aligned_storage` [type trait](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) for a solution portable to GCC compilers:

`typedef boost::aligned_storage<__BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__, __BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__> AlignedType;`

Comment: Won't your size_t chunkSize = 1+payloadSize; increase the size by 1 byte, while doing a pointer-cast to uint64_t*, which you then decrease by 1 actually decrease the pointer sizeof(uint64_t)? Which essentially means that when someone tries to allocate X bytes, you actually just allocate X-(sizeof(uint64_t)-1) bytes and return such a pointer?

Comment: @Simon: `allocator::allocate` takes the number of **elements** as its parameter, not the size in bytes. See http://cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/allocator/allocate/

Comment: Renamed some variables so that it's more evident when it represents number of elements.

Comment: Hey thanks, this looks really nice. As I'm using c++0x, I suppose I can use alignof(std::max_align_t) instead of __BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__ (as soon as it gets implemented in GCC, at least in 4.6 it is not there yet). Marking answer as accepted.

Comment: @bluescarni: To substitute `uint64_t`, I think you can directly use `std::max_align_t` instead of `alignof(std::max_align_t)` (I'm not yet versed in all the new features of C++0x). You'll have to do some pointer conversions to be able to store the chunk size in a `std::max_align_t` element.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great series about this written on altdevblogaday by Paul Laska. Here's the link to the first article: http://altdevblogaday.org/2011/04/11/ready-set-allocate-part-1/

In the article he takes care about block-size allocations and alignment issues. It should provide a well-thought and well-written solution for taking care of your deallocate-issues.

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320264/how-to-align-pointer/6320500#6320500) regarding storing a value in the beginning of the block. You can slightly modify it for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The two main methods of object size tracking that I'm aware of are implicitly in a size-segregated allocator with metadata off to the side (e.g. Kingsley-style allocator), or tacking the size in front of the object as an object header (e.g. dlmalloc).  A pretty awful third solution would be maintaining a map of every allocated object and its size.  That map, of course, would be managed by another allocator.

I think you're on the correct track, and it's good that you're aware of alignment considerations.  I tried to look up some information on mt_alloc to see if there are alternatives or surprises, but such information does not seem to be easily forthcoming.  Some allocators have a method to query an object size (which may or may not be cheap to do).  If the deallocate function requires passing the size explicitly, then I would guess no such function exists, but you never know.

If alignment is important, your calculation will need to be tweaked a bit, since the allocator probably will not return memory aligned appropriately for you.  If you know nothing about the alignment of returned pointers, you need something like:

```
struct object_header {
    size_t size;
};

void * buf = xxmalloc (2 * alignment + size + sizeof(object_header));
void * alignedPtr = (void *) (((size_t) buf + sizeof(object_header) + alignment - 1) & ~(alignment - 1));
```

If mt_alloc cannot tolerate freeing objects on interior pointers, then this scheme raises a problem for you because by padding out extra space for alignment, you no longer know the original address returned to you.  In that case you may need to store an extra field in your header.

Depending on how mt_alloc manages memory internally, tacking on an extra header can also give you substantial overhead.  In a size-segregated allocator, tacking on this header can give you up to 2x space overhead on objects up to page-size, at which point you can pay up to the cost of an extra page per object.  In other allocators, this may not be an issue, but it's something to look out for.

Comment: Since when was 8-byte alignment standard for malloc? The standard states: "The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably
aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type
of object and then used to access such an object or an array
of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is
explicitly deallocated).", which is clearly platform (and compiler) specific.

Comment: You're right, I've been working in GNU land for too long.  In fact I should know better because we've been wrapping layers around our allocators to enforce this.