# Is it correct to create a class instance through malloc and instead placement new?

Tags: c++, object, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, placement-new

Here is a class.

```
class A
{
public:
A()
private:
int m_a;
};
```

Can we create an object of a class instead placement operator `new` and using `malloc`, like this:

```
void* a = malloc(sizeof(A)); // allocate raw memory 
A* obj = reinterpret_cast< A* > ( a ); // assign to the adress
a->A() // call the constructor
```

Is it correct? If not, can we construct an object using `malloc` and instead placement `new` (using some other C techniques)?

Comment: Does this even compile?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, `invalid use of A::A`.

Comment: The code to call the constructor is `new(obj) A`  , not `a->A()`. And yes, that should work.

Comment: I dont know. I need to understand it is possible to create an instance trough malloc and instead placement new, i.e using some C techniques ?

Comment: new(obj) A this part uses new, my question is, how to do sush things instead using new

Comment: You can't, this is the only way

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use `placement new` after getting the raw memory from `malloc`.

```
class S
{};
...
void *mem = malloc(sizeof(S));
S* s = new (mem) S(); //this is the so called "placement new"
```

Then explicitly call its destructor.

```
s->~S();
free(mem);
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets clear up the terminology a bit. 'Placement new' is the means of invoking the constructor *only*, it does not allocate memory. Regular new is more analogous to malloc because it allocates memory.

The proper way to use malloc in C++ is to malloc and *then* use placement new.

```
void* a = malloc(sizeof(A)); // allocate raw memory 
A* obj = reinterpret_cast< A* > (a);
new(obj) A(); // placement new syntax runs the constructor of A()
```

Or further simplified:

```
void* a = malloc(sizeof(A)); // allocate raw memory 
A* obj = new(a) A(); // placement new syntax runs the constructor of A()
```

However, there is (typically) little reason to do this. If you need to use a specific allocator, you can define a custom operator new overload.

Comment: I would combine the second and third lines into `A* obj = new(a) A();`, which would avoid the need for a `reinterpret_cast` to an invalid type (the pointer returned from `malloc` does not point to an `A` until the `A` is constructed).

Comment: In your code you have use new. The question is, how to do sush things instead using new(obj) A() ?

Comment: @Վարդան Գրիգորյան : You are misunderstanding: new in this context is called placement new and it does not allocate memory. It invokes the constructor of A() only.

Comment: @ՎարդանԳրիգորյան: It isn't possible to call a constructor directly without using `new`. (Or to put it differently, placement new *is* the `C++` mechanism for calling a constructor directly).

Comment: Ok, is it possible to call the constructor explicitly, using a pointer which returned by malloc ?

Comment: @Վարդան Գրիգորյան : Yes, placement new is the syntax for explicitly invoking the constructor.

Comment: Shouldn't the second line read `A* obj = new(a) A();` in the simplified version?

Comment: @Avi Ginsburg: Yes, careless pasting mistake, fixed ;)

Answer (score 1):

Beware, malloc returns an address that is aligned to 8 bytes. If your class just have a

```
char a[6];
```

member you are wasting 2 bytes (well if you have only 1 char or 1 bool you'll be wastin 7 bytes), while if you have a

```
v4si a;
```

vector of 4 bytes for SIMD instructions, you could have a wrong alignment wich require extra instructions to re-align it correctly.

**Not wasting memory:**

```
class TinyClass{
    char c[3];
public:
    TinyClass( char c1, char c2, char c3){
        c[0] = c1; c[1] = c2; c[2] = c3;
    }
};
```

Basically you have to create more than one object at a time (but they also must be destroyed at same time, so probably that's not suitable for you)

```
#include <new> //not needed if you already include any STL header

int number_of_items = 6;
void* a = malloc(sizeof(TinyClass)*number_of_items);
TinyClass * Ptr = reinterpret_cast< TinyClass* > (a);
for(int i=0; i<number_of_items; i++)
    new(&Ptr[i]) TinyClass('a','b','c');

//later
for(int i=0; i<number_of_items; i++)
    Ptr[i].~TinyClass();  //destructor
Ptr = NULL; // or Ptr = nullptr; if you have c++11
free(a);
```

.

**Forcing alignement bigger than 8 bytes:**

[C++ possible implementation of aligned malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6320500/1829943)

Of course forget what I said if you don't mind performance or memory waste ^^, because that's a bit bloat code.

Is that the same in C++? Not exactly, using "new" in c++ returns a pointer wich is at least aligned to what is needed, but there's no guarantee the implementation will not have a bigger alignement)