# How do I round to the next 32-bit alignment?

Tags: c++, alignment

Packets coming over a network have padding bytes added at the end for alignment. I want to skip these bytes but the packet size is variable but known. Given a number `n`, how do I round it up to the next 4-byte alignment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840410/how-to-align-a-pointer-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For any integer `n` and any stride `k` (both positive), you can compute the smallest multiple of `k` that's not smaller than `n` via:

```
(n + k - 1) / k * k
```

This uses the fact that integral division truncates.

Comment: So for 4-byte alignment it would be `(n + 32 - 1) / 32 * 32`?

Comment: @templateboy: If you're counting in bits, yes, though that's pretty unlikely. You should probably count in bytes, i.e. in the size of the smallest allocatable (and hence alignable) unit of storage.

Answer (score 0):

Another version. n is the number you want to alight to 4 (say k). Formula would be=n+k-n%k (where % is modulus)

For example (in Unix bc calculator)

```
k=4
n=551
n+k-n%k
552
```

to check that it is aligned:

```
scale=4
552/4
138.0000
```

Comment: if n is already aligned this adds an extra k:  e.g. n=4; k=4; 4+4-(4%4)= 8, not 4. it works, if you check n%k != 0 first, but in some code there are penalties for taking a branch and @Kerrek SB's solution is preferred.