# How to free aligned pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, alignment

I found two simple and sufficient ways to align pointers. Extended discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4840428/7010551). 
Here they are:

```
void* allocate_align_1(size_t size, uintptr_t align)
{
    void* addr = malloc(size + align);

    uintptr_t aligned_addr = (uintptr_t)addr;    
    aligned_addr += align - (aligned_addr % align);

    return (void*)aligned_addr;
}

void* allocate_align_2(size_t size, uintptr_t align)
{
    void* addr = malloc(size + align);

    uintptr_t aligned_addr = (uintptr_t)addr;    
    aligned_addr = (aligned_addr + (align - 1)) & -align;

    return (void*)aligned_addr;
}
```

Link on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd157366be6408b5).

My question is how `deallocate_align(void* addr, uintptr_t align)` function can be implemented?
Can pointer which was returned by `malloc` be restored from `addr` and align `align`? Then it should just be passed to `free`.

Comment: You need to store additional information since there's no way to know (in the `deallocate` function) whether the pointer returned from your function was the same as the pointer that `malloc` returned. Also, is there a reason that you think that the pointer returned by `malloc` is not sufficiently aligned?

Comment: thanks. fixed now it allocate align bytes more.

Comment: The code invokes undefined behaviour and there is no way for this code to work, as you loose relevant information. Arithmetics on a pointer converted to an integer is not defined. Why do you re-invent the wheel with problematic code? Use `aligned_alloc`.

Comment: @user3386109 suppose I want to align on 64 bytes.

Comment: @Olaf he uses `uintptr_t`. Isn't that type to be used for pointer calculations?

Comment: @Olaf I just want to figure out how this thing can be implemented.

Comment: @axalis actually you are right. I was thinking to fast.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Read my comment carefully, then the standard. `uintptr_t` only guaranteed conversion ptr->`uintptr_t` and back. No guarantee if arithmetics is done on the integer inbetween (I used such code myself, but I know my platforms, here we don't).

Comment: If the base address *can* be reversed from the pointer you return, you would need to remember the alignment - so why not keep it simple and reliable, and remember the value returned by `malloc`?

Comment: @Viktor: That's what the standard library exists for. It can do things you cannot do in standard (i.e. portable) C code.

Comment: @Olaf is it possible to guarantee if arithmetic is done on the pointer correctly?

Comment: @Viktor: Please provide a reference to the standard defining "correctly".

Comment: @Olaf I meant well-defined not undefined behavior.

Comment: @Viktor: Where did I even mention "undefined behaviour"?

Comment: @Olaf "Arithmetics on a pointer converted to an integer is not defined." My question is how to make arithmetic on pointer "defined".

Comment: In general you could actually cast the pointer to `char *` and do the arithmetic on that pointer type, or?

Comment: I can cast to `int*` or whatever as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pointer (and possibly the alignment size) is your only information, you'd need to store some kind of metadata (the original pointer, alignment offset etc.) somewhere. It might be before your allocated memory block, which you can then access when performing the deallocation, or some registry (e.g. hashtable or map) somewhere else, where you will store the metadata and retrieve them according to the address when de-allocating.

One possible (oversimplified) implementation (not tested, just for illustration - in the real case, the stored value will also need to be aligned properly, if `align` is smaller than the suitable alignment for `uintptr_t`):

```
void* allocate_align_1(size_t size, uintptr_t align)
{
    void* addr = malloc(size + align + sizeof(uintptr_t));

    uintptr_t aligned_addr = (uintptr_t)addr + sizeof(uintptr_t);    
    aligned_addr += align - (aligned_addr % align);

    // store the original address
    *(uintptr_t*)(aligned_addr - sizeof(uintptr_t)) = (uintptr_t)addr;

    return (void*)aligned_addr;
}
```

Then in deallocate, you can access the data (for proper use there could/should be some check of a guard value or similar to make sure the correct data is really there), an example without checking:

```
void deallocate(void * ptr)
{
    uintptr_t orig_ptr = *(uintptr_t*)((uintptr_t)ptr - sizeof(uintptr_t));
    free((void*)orig_ptr);
}
```

Comment: could you give an example how to store and use such metadata?

Comment: What is the metadata in C. What is the _'some registry somewhere else'_?

Comment: @PeterJ "Metadata" is some extra data about the pointer (e.g. the original address or the alignment offset) which will allow to retrieve the original pointer to be freed. Registry might be e.g. a hash map storing metadata for each particular allocated pointer (somewhere else meaning that it is an extra structure not connected with the allocated memory directly).

Comment: Updated with an (untested) example how the deallocation function might access the data in the principle.

Comment: `*(uintptr_t)(aligned_addr - sizeof(uintptr_t)) = (uintptr_t)addr;` -> `*(uintptr_t *)(aligned_addr - sizeof(uintptr_t)) = (uintptr_t)addr;` and same problem for deallocation: `uintptr_t orig_ptr = *(uintptr_t)((uintptr_t)ptr - sizeof(uintptr_t));` -> `uintptr_t orig_ptr = *(uintptr_t *)((uintptr_t)ptr - sizeof(uintptr_t));`

Comment: Yep, I actually didn't try to compile it :)

Comment: Good answer. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to work. For example, a call such as `allocate_align_1( 4, 4);` is going to generate `SIGBUS` on 64-bit SPARC at  `*(uintptr_t*)(aligned_addr - sizeof(uintptr_t)) = (uintptr_t)addr;`  In short, there's  no guarantee that `aligned_address - sizeof( uintptr_t )` will produce an address "suitable for any use".  Or in my example, suitable for storing a 64-bit pointer value, which on 64-bit SPARC has to be on an 8-byte boundary, IIRC.

Comment: @ Andrew Henle From this discussion I learnt that better is to use library functions otherwise no guarantees.

Comment: @AndrewHenle True, the stored value will also need to be properly aligned if the value of `align` is small, updated the answer with the note.

Answer (score 0):

If you use gnu C/C++ compilers malloc is already aligned

> The address of a block returned by malloc or realloc in GNU systems is
>   always a multiple of eight (or sixteen on 64-bit systems).

So if your align is needed for the processor - you do need to align.

If you need a non standard align you will need to keep the original pointer as well for example:

```
typedef struct {
  void *original;
  void *aligned;
} mypointer;

    void* allocate_align_(mypointer *p; size_t size, uintptr_t align)
    {
        p -> original = malloc(size + align);
    ...
    //aligning code here
        p ->aligned = ... //(some math & pointer operations) do not change the p -> original
        return p- > aligned;
    }

    void align_free(mypointer *p) 
    {
        free(p -> original);
    }
```

it is not real code do no error checking etc. just the idea

Comment: `malloc` is not even part of the gcc compiler toolchain. t is a freestanding implementation without libc. So it is not clear how you can even make any assimptions. And OP seems to want to specify an arbitrary alignment, which `malloc` does not provide. The code is clumsy to use, e.g. other functions have to be aware of the `struct`.

Comment: It is true that `malloc` should normally return pointers aligned for any use, however you might want to align differently for e.g. SSE etc. which might have different alignment requirements than the CPU.

Comment: Also for this to work, you would actually need to return and keep the entire struct, not just the `p->aligned`, as there is no way to retrieve `p` or `p->original` from the value of `p->aligned` ... however if returning just `p`, it might be a possible solution.

Comment: @Olaf Great comment !!!! https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Aligned-Memory-Blocks.html     https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Basic-Allocation

Comment: @axalis what for? You have the original pointer stored. And you use it for free

Comment: @PeterJ: Reading comments **carefully** and **understanding** seems to be a diominishing virtue. From your text "… gnu C/C++ compilers …". My comment **explicitly** was about the gcc **compiler toolchain**. From the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/Standards.html#C-Language) : "_ GCC aims towards being usable as a conforming freestanding implementation, or **as the compiler** for a conforming hosted implementation._" (emphasis mine). It explicitly excludes the library!

Comment: @Olaf Reading OP questions **carefully** and **understanding** seems to be a diminishing virtue. if you exclude the libraries any discussion about any library function including malloc() & free() is pointless.

Comment: @PeterJ: Where did I say to exclude them? You are just trying to explain apples using oranges. This is not related to the gcc compiler, but the libc, of which glibc is **one possible** implementation. And that one provides a much more straight and easy way.

Comment: @PeterJ Yes, actually I missed that the `mypointer` in your example is a global variable and I thought it is just defining the struct. However that way you can only ever manage a single pointer which is not so flexible (the OP might e.g. want to allocate more blocks at the same time).

Comment: @Olaf sorry mate. you missed the first word if. But anyway - please find any malloc impementation which does not return aligned value. I do know any.

Comment: @PeterJ: On an 8 bit system alignment past a byte does not make much sense. It worked fine on my system. Nevertheless, you intentionally only pick part of my comments, intentionally ignoring the more relevant parts. This leads nowhere, I'm out. You have the last word.

Comment: @PeterJ Aligned to *what*?  The C standard merely requires that the alignment be suitable for "generic" strictly-standard-conforming C.  Not for any platform-specific uses that may have much more strict alignment considerations.  Saying "malloc is already aligned" in a vacuum is about as useful as saying "all char buffers are already aligned".  No, they're **NOT**.

Comment: @Olaf _'You have the last word.'_ of course because I am right. But this one was quite interesting - _'malloc is not even part of the gcc compiler toolchain. t is a freestanding implementation without libc.'_ And I stupid believed documentations : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html   And 8 bit systems - great example - what about intel 4004?