# Please help me understand this bit-wise manipulation of pointer values

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I am not able to understand why is addr being typecasted to long, and then complemented with expression.. basically the whole line involving the calculation of peekAddr

```
void *addr;
char *peekAddr ;
peekAddr = (char *) ((long)addr & ~(sizeof(long) - 1 ) ) ;
peekWord = ptrace( PTRACE_PEEKDATA, pid, peekAddr, NULL ) ;
```

Comment: it basically aligns addr to long word boundary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227897/solve-the-memory-alignment-in-c-interview-question-that-stumped-me

Comment: thanks. i am still not able to understand how it aligns memory

Answer (score 5):

```
sizeof (long)     = (0)00000100
sizeof(long)-1    = (0)00000011
~(sizeof(long)-1) = (1)11111100
```

so 2 bits set to 0 make the address aligned to 4 bytes. additionally it's mostly used when the address was already incremented by sizeof(long)-1

Answer (score 4):

It's cast to `long` because (1) you can't do any operations on a `void*` except cast it and (2) on the author's platform, a `void*` value just so happens to fit in a `long`. He should really have used `uintptr_t` or `size_t` instead.

What the piece of code does:

```
sizeof(long) - 1
```

is most likely either 3 or 7, depending on the platform.

```
~(sizeof(long) - 1)
```

is a bitmask that selects all but the last few bits.

```
((long)addr & ~(sizeof(long) - 1))
```

is `addr` rounded down/aligned to address a `long`-sized chunk. Rounding occurs because the last lg(3) or lg(7) bits are zeros while the rest is copied from `addr` (where lg is integer binary logarithm).

Comment: Nitpick: It's not the last 3 or 7 bits that are cleared, but the low 2 and 3 bits, respectively. (Since 3 is 11 binary and 7 is 111 binary.)

Comment: Not in your last sentence. :)

Comment: @greyfade: that's slightly embarassing ;) Fixed, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really ugly, unportable way of doing

```
peakAddr = (char *)addr - ((uintptr_t)addr & -(uintptr_t)sizeof(long));
```

Note that the original version not only relies on successful round trip conversion of pointers to `long` and back, but also on `size_t` (the type of the result of the `sizeof` operator) being the same width or wider than `long`. If it's not, the bitmask generated with `~` would zero-extend in the upper bits and obliterate part of the pointer.

Basically, you should make a mental note that whatever program you found this in is bad code and not look to it as a source of ideas...

Answer (score 1):

you basically make peekAddr always aligned on sizeof(long) adresses. the line generates a bitmask and binary ands this to the peek address. 
The line strips the last sizeof(long)-1 bits from the peekAddr.

hth

Mario

Answer (score 1):

This will have a bug on some compilers where `sizeof(long) < sizeof(char*)`, such as Microsoft's.

`sizeof(long)-1` is creating a bit mask corresponding to the size of a `long`. This is a trick that only works on numbers that are a power of 2.  The `~` in front inverts it, so now it's a mask of all the address bits that should remain unchanged when you're trying to align an address. The bitwise `&` is clearing the bottom bits of the address to make it align.