# Alignment considerations when I treat a memory area as an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct, alignment

Let's consider that I have defined a memory area like (*Note*: `uint8` means `unsigned char`):

```
uint8 myMemoryArea[1024];
```

And I have a struct like:

```
typedef struct
{
   uint8 * ptrToMyVar; 
   uint8 otherVar;
} myStruct_type;
```

I want to consider `myMemoryArea` as being an array of `myStruct_type`, so I would want to perform a random access to the memory area like, for example:

```
myStruct_type * myPtrToStruct = (* myStruct_type)(&(myMemoryArea[ELEMENT_TO_ACCESS * sizeof(myStruct_type)]));
myPtrToStruct->otherVar =  2;
```

Is this machine independent code? Should I expect troubles with alignment or padding?
I guess padding is OK here as long as I use `sizeof`.

Should I ensure that `myMemoryArea` starts from an address divisible by `sizeof(* char)` - perhaps defining it as an array of pointers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no guarantee that `myMemoryArea` will be appropriately aligned.  Depending on your CPU and O/S and compiler, you may get crashes or very slow access to misaligned data.  (See also: [Solve the memory alignment in C interview question that stumped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227897/solve-the-memory-alignment-in-c-interview-question-that-stumped-me/)).

Consider what happens if your variable is declared in this context:

```
double d1;
uint8  c1;
uint8  myMemoryArea[1024];
uint8  c2;
douebl d2;
```

There's every reason to expect `d1` to be properly aligned; the compiler will be failing you horribly if it is not.  There's no reason to expect any unusual treatment for `c1`; a single byte can be stored on any alignment.  The `myMemoryArea` data also does not have to be aligned specially; there might be no space around it, and it may well be at an odd address.  The `c2` variable doesn't need special treatment; `d2` will be properly aligned (and there's likely to be 6 bytes unused space in the data.

If `myMemoryArea` is on an odd-byte alignment, and you use a RISC machine to access the memory structure, you will most likely get a SIGBUS error.  On an Intel machine, you may get very slow access instead.

Comment: I agree about the first part, but the example I think isn't valid; there's nothing preventing a compiler from re-ordering local variables to optimize alignment and minimize losses.

Comment: It depends on context; it depends on CPU, OS, compiler.  I've said that. (I should have mentioned oddball stuff like '#pragma pack' and compiler optimization options too.)  There's nothing to stop every one of those 5 variables being individually aligned on a 16-byte boundary.  Consider other contexts, such as 'there is a `struct botched {` line immediately before and a `};` line immediately after the 5 variables.  Now the compiler has no latitude to reorder the variables (but it could still align them conveniently).  No; nothing is guaranteed.  I didn't claim it was.

Comment: What if I'll define `myMemoryArea` as `double myMemoryArea[1024/ SIZE_OF_DOUBLE];` ? Would that ensure alignment? Considering that I know `SIZE_OF_DOUBLE`...

Comment: If you use `double` instead of `uint8`, and if `long double`, `uintmax_t`, `void *` and `void (*)(void)` do not have more stringent alignment requirements than `double`, then you'd be OK on alignment, though you'd need to cast the address to `(char *)` before computing offsets (as otherwise, your offsets will be off by a factor of `sizeof(double)`).  You could create yourself a `union Strictest { long double ld; double d; void *vp; void      (*fp)(void); long long ll; uintmax_t mi; };` and use that in `union Memory { union Strictest a; uint8 m[1024]; };` to get the memory properly aligned.