# Performance worsens when using SSE (Simple addition of integer arrays)

Tags: c, sse, simd

I'm trying to use SSE intrinsics to add two 32-bit signed int arrays. But I'm getting very poor performance compared to a linear addition.

Platform - Intel Core i3 550, GCC 4.4.3, Ubuntu 10.04 (bit old, yeah)

```
#define ITER 1000
typedef union sint4_u {
        __m128i v;
        sint32_t x[4];
} sint4;
```

The functions:

```
void compute(sint32_t *a, sint32_t *b, sint32_t *c) {
        sint32_t len = 96000;
        sint32_t i, j;

        __m128i x __attribute__ ((aligned(16)));
        __m128i y __attribute__ ((aligned(16)));
        sint4 z;

        for(j = 0; j < ITER; j++) {
                for(i = 0; i < len; i += 4) {
                        x = _mm_set_epi32(a[i + 0], a[i + 1], a[i + 2], a[i + 3]);
                        y = _mm_set_epi32(b[i + 0], b[i + 1], b[i + 2], b[i + 3]);
                        z.v = _mm_add_epi32(x, y); 
                        c[i + 0] = z.x[3];
                        c[i + 1] = z.x[2];
                        c[i + 2] = z.x[1];
                        c[i + 3] = z.x[0];
                }   
        }   

        return;
}

void compute_s(sint32_t *a, sint32_t *b, sint32_t *c) {
        sint32_t len = 96000;
        sint32_t i, j;
        for(j = 0; j < ITER; j++) {
                for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
                }   
        }   
        return;
}
```

The results:

```
➜  C  gcc -msse4.2 simd.c
➜  C  ./a.out            
Time Elapsed (SSE): 612.520000 mS
Time Elapsed (Scalar): 401.713000 mS
➜  C  gcc -O3 -msse4.2 simd.c
➜  C  ./a.out                
Time Elapsed (SSE): 135.124000 mS
Time Elapsed (Scalar): 46.438000 mS
```

On using `-O3`, the SSE version becomes 3 times slower (!!). What am I doing wrong? Even if I skip the loading back to `c` in `compute`, it still takes an extra 100 ms without any optimizations.

**EDIT - as suggested in the comments, I replaced _mm_set with _mm_load, here are the updated times -**

```
➜  C    gcc audproc.c -msse4    
➜  C    ./a.out             
Time Elapsed (SSE): 303.931000 mS
Time Elapsed (Scalar): 413.701000 mS
➜  C    gcc -O3 audproc.c -msse4
➜  C    ./a.out                 
Time Elapsed (SSE): 82.532000 mS
Time Elapsed (Scalar): 48.104000 mS
```

Much much better, but still nowhere close to the theoretical gain of 4x. Also, why is my vectorization slower at `O3`? Also, how do I get rid of this warning? (I tried adding `__vector__` to my declaration but got more warnings instead. :( )

```
audproc.c: In function ‘compute’:
audproc.c:54: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘_mm_load_si128’ from incompatible pointer type /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include/emmintrin.h:677: note: expected ‘const long long int __vector__ *’ but argument is of type ‘const sint32_t *’
```

Comment: Oh god... not again... [Please don't kill puppies.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23186488/922184)

Comment: Oh, let me try changing that.

Comment: At least with `-O3`, even gcc 4.4 should vectorize the loop better than your hand-coded version. Look at the assembly (use the `-S` flag and maybe `-fverbose-asm`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integer dot product using SSE/AVX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186348/integer-dot-product-using-sse-avx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, in order to get the performance benefits of SIMD you should avoid scalar operations in your loop, i.e. get rid of the `_mm_set_epi32` pseudo-intrinsics and the union for storing SIMD results. Here is a fixed version of your function:

```
void compute(const sint32_t *a, const sint32_t *b, sint32_t *c)
{
    sint32_t len = 96000;
    sint32_t i, j;

    for(j = 0; j < ITER; j++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < len; i += 4)
        {
            __m128i x = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&a[i]);
            __m128i y = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&b[i]);
            __m128i z = _mm_add_epi32(x, y); 
            _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)&c[i], z);
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Although 96000 is divisible by four if a value of `len` is used which is not a multiple of four (e.g 96001) this will have a problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - yes, this worked great. One question though, you used `_mm_loadu` for loading data. My arrays were already 16-byte aligned, so I switched to `_mm_load` to get better performance, but saw no difference in the times.

Is there no penalty in using `_mm_loadu` if the addresses are aligned?

Comment: @AnkushJain, [since Nahelem the latency and throughput of _mm_load and _mm_loadu are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648158/how-many-cycle-does-need-for-put-a-data-into-simd-register/20654007#20654007) so there is not reason to use _mm_load anymore.