# Using vector instructions to find aggregate sum of array

Tags: c++, assembly, vectorization, simd, avx2

I was trying to learn some intel intrinsics to use vector instructions. Here is the code I have written using vectors defined in `immintrin.h`.
Compilation is done using `g++ vadd.cpp -O3 -o vadd -std=c++17 -Wall -march=broadwell -fno-tree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec-all=vec.rpt`.
Results are
`Vectorized time -----------> 327888 and sum 511116419`
`Non Vectorized time -------> 553156 and sum 511116419`
Nothing in the vector report. I am unable to find where I am doing it wrong, but every time the results are the same. The vectorized sum is taking more time than non vectorized sum.
A reason which I came out is lots of vector instructions are generated for the load data into vector. Is there any way to reduce them or any way to optimize it?
Note: TimeStamp is the header file for measuring time differences in nanosec and not included in the code.

```cpp
int callVector(int data[], int i) {
    __m256i dest1 = _mm256_set1_epi32(0);
    __m256i dest2 = _mm256_set1_epi32(0);
    for (int i=0; i<iteration; i+=8) {
        __m256i temp1 = _mm256_loadu_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i const*>(data + i));
        i = i+8;
        __m256i temp2 = _mm256_loadu_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i const*>(data + i));
        // sum of adjacent vector elements
        dest1 = _mm256_add_epi32(dest1, temp1);
        dest2 = _mm256_add_epi32(dest2, temp2);
    }
    __m256i temp1 = _mm256_loadu_si256(&dest1);
    __m256i temp2 = _mm256_loadu_si256(&dest2);
    // sum of adjacent vector elements
    __m256i sum = _mm256_hadd_epi32(temp1, temp2);
    __m128i sum_high = _mm256_extracti128_si256(sum, 1);
    __m128i sum4 = _mm_add_epi32(sum_high, _mm256_castsi256_si128(sum));
    int ans[4];
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)&ans, sum4);
    return ans[0] + ans[1] + ans[2] + ans[3]; 
}

int callNonVector(int data[], int start) {
    int ans = 0;
    for (int i=start; i<iteration; i++) {
        ans += data[i];
    }
    return ans;
}

int main () {
    int idx[1000000] __attribute__((aligned(64)));
    for (int i=0; i<iteration; i++) {
        idx[i] = rand() % 1024;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    TimeStamp start{};
    sum = callVector(idx, 0);
    TimeStamp::IntegralType diff = TimeStamp{} - start;
    cout<<"Vectorized time -----------> "<<diff<<" and sum "<<sum<<"\n";
    TimeStamp start2{};
    sum = callNonVector(idx, 0);
    TimeStamp::IntegralType diff2 = TimeStamp{} - start2;
    cout<<"Non Vectorized time -------> "<<diff2<<" and sum "<<sum<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the assembly code generated for the above code.

```
0000000000000d60 <_Z10callVectorPii>:
 d60:   8b 05 fa 14 20 00       mov    0x2014fa(%rip),%eax        # 202260 <iteration>
 d66:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
 d68:   7e 66                   jle    dd0 <_Z10callVectorPii+0x70>
 d6a:   ff c8                   dec    %eax
 d6c:   c5 e1 ef db             vpxor  %xmm3,%xmm3,%xmm3
 d70:   c1 e8 04                shr    $0x4,%eax
 d73:   c5 fd 6f d3             vmovdqa %ymm3,%ymm2
 d77:   48 c1 e0 06             shl    $0x6,%rax
 d7b:   48 01 f8                add    %rdi,%rax
 d7e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 d80:   c5 ed fe 07             vpaddd (%rdi),%ymm2,%ymm0
 d84:   c5 e5 fe 4f 20          vpaddd 0x20(%rdi),%ymm3,%ymm1
 d89:   48 89 fa                mov    %rdi,%rdx
 d8c:   48 83 c7 40             add    $0x40,%rdi
 d90:   c5 fd 6f d0             vmovdqa %ymm0,%ymm2
 d94:   c5 fd 6f d9             vmovdqa %ymm1,%ymm3
 d98:   48 39 d0                cmp    %rdx,%rax
 d9b:   75 e3                   jne    d80 <_Z10callVectorPii+0x20>
 d9d:   c4 e2 7d 02 c1          vphaddd %ymm1,%ymm0,%ymm0
 da2:   c4 e3 7d 39 c1 01       vextracti128 $0x1,%ymm0,%xmm1
 da8:   c5 f9 fe c1             vpaddd %xmm1,%xmm0,%xmm0
 dac:   c4 e3 79 16 c2 02       vpextrd $0x2,%xmm0,%edx
 db2:   c5 f9 7e c0             vmovd  %xmm0,%eax
 db6:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
 db8:   c4 e3 79 16 c2 01       vpextrd $0x1,%xmm0,%edx
 dbe:   01 c2                   add    %eax,%edx
 dc0:   c4 e3 79 16 c0 03       vpextrd $0x3,%xmm0,%eax
 dc6:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
 dc8:   c5 f8 77                vzeroupper 
 dcb:   c3                      retq   
 dcc:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
 dd0:   c5 f9 ef c0             vpxor  %xmm0,%xmm0,%xmm0
 dd4:   c5 fd 6f c8             vmovdqa %ymm0,%ymm1
 dd8:   eb c3                   jmp    d9d <_Z10callVectorPii+0x3d>
 dda:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

```
0000000000000e50 <_Z13callNonVectorPii>:
 e50:   8b 15 0a 14 20 00       mov    0x20140a(%rip),%edx        # 202260 <iteration>
 e56:   39 d6                   cmp    %edx,%esi
 e58:   7d 26                   jge    e80 <_Z13callNonVectorPii+0x30>
 e5a:   ff ca                   dec    %edx
 e5c:   48 63 ce                movslq %esi,%rcx
 e5f:   45 31 c0                xor    %r8d,%r8d
 e62:   29 f2                   sub    %esi,%edx
 e64:   48 8d 04 8f             lea    (%rdi,%rcx,4),%rax
 e68:   48 01 ca                add    %rcx,%rdx
 e6b:   48 8d 54 97 04          lea    0x4(%rdi,%rdx,4),%rdx
 e70:   44 03 00                add    (%rax),%r8d
 e73:   48 83 c0 04             add    $0x4,%rax
 e77:   48 39 d0                cmp    %rdx,%rax
 e7a:   75 f4                   jne    e70 <_Z13callNonVectorPii+0x20>
 e7c:   44 89 c0                mov    %r8d,%eax
 e7f:   c3                      retq   
 e80:   45 31 c0                xor    %r8d,%r8d
 e83:   44 89 c0                mov    %r8d,%eax
 e86:   c3                      retq   
 e87:   66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 e8e:   00 00
```

Comment: You might try to invert the call of functions for testing. The processor may take time to understand it must enter in turbo mode

Comment: There is very likely a duplicate for this, but the main problems with your vectorized code are the weird way you load your data (just use `_mm256_loadu_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i const*>(data + i))` and that you are using slow horizontal adds and reductions within the loop (this needs to be done only at the very end).

Comment: [Performance worsens when using SSE (Simple addition of integer arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24446516) is a duplicate of the `set` vs. `loadu` inefficiency.  Also note that your `_mm256_set_epi32` was reversing the order of elements within the vector vs. memory order, and the compiler would have had to optimize *that* away to optimize the set to a loadu of contiguous elements.

Comment: BTW, if you enabled full optimization (`-O3` includes auto-vectorization), the plain scalar code would have gotten optimized and been a lot faster, making it mostly unnecessary to vectorize by hand (except as a learning exercise before you move on to more complicated stuff.)

Comment: @chtz: I found separate duplicates for those 2 showstopper performance bugs.

Comment: @chtz I have made changes and got some improvements also (edited the code in the quotesion).
@PeterCordes I was just trying to learn intel intrinsics and how to do profiling and optimizations. Have done compilation with auto-vectorize
The results are
`Vectorized time -----------> 322236 and sum 511116419`
`Non Vectorized time -------> 296231 and sum 511116419`
Are these numbers justified or there is further scope of optimizations?
PS: going through the links provided for details.