# sse C++ memory commands

Tags: c++, sse

SSE asm has SQRTPS command.

SQRTPS command have 2 versions:

```
SQRTPS xmm1, xmm2
SQRTPS xmm1, m128
```

gcc/clang/vs (all) compilers have helper function `_mm_sqrt_ps`.

But `_mm_sqrt_ps` can work only with preloaded xmm (with _mm_set_ps / _mm_load_ps).

From Visual Studio, for example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8z67bwwk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

What I expect:

```
__attribute__((aligned(16))) float data[4];
__attribute__((aligned(16))) float result[4];
asm{
    sqrtps xmm0, data             // DIRECTLY FROM MEMORY
    movaps result, xmm0
}
```

What I have (in C):

```
__attribute__((aligned(16))) float data[4];
__attribute__((aligned(16))) float result[4];
auto xmm  = _mm_load_ps(&data)   // or _mm_set_ps 
xmm = _mm_sqrt_ps(xmm);
_mm_store_ps(&result[0], xmm);
```

(in asm):

```
movaps xmm1, data
sqrtps xmm0, xmm1               // FROM REGISTER
movaps result, xmm0
```

---

In other words, I would like to see something like this:

```
__attribute__((aligned(16))) float data[4];
__attribute__((aligned(16))) float result[4];
auto xmm = _mm_sqrt_ps(data);                  // DIRECTLY FROM MEMORY, no need to load (because there is such instruction)
_mm_store_ps(&result[0], xmm);
```

Comment: Probably because both code snippets have the same behavior (so the first is perhaps not faster than the second)

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch Well - I believe they have the same behavior. But... why it not faster???

Comment: Because current out-of-order multiscalar processors are much more complex than what you believe!

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch - Well you're wrong... It is not faster according to this http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf , for Ivy Bridge `sqrtps` have the same latency for both x/m operations (page 182)

Comment: Speed of individual machine instructions don't matter (and don't even make sense, because of cache, ILP, branch prediction, ...) these days. Benchmark an entire application!

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch - This is not seriously. You show me how to close my eyes on this problem, not to understand it. And you may see the same behavior for ALL other machines (there are all x86 arch's there)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, this is a good question (even if not worded well). I don't know if the sqrt form has the same behaviour but I know from experience that the mulps form does not https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134279/difference-in-performance-between-msvc-and-gcc-for-highly-optimized-matrix-multp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is that you can't control this , at least for aligned loads, with intrinsics. It's up to the compiler to decide if it uses SQRTPS xmm1, xmm2 or SQRTPS xmm1, m128. If you want to be 100% certain then you have to write it in assembly. This is one of the deficiencies of intrinsics (at least as they are currently implemented) in my opinion.

Some code can help explain this.

We can get GCC (64-bit with -O3) to generate both version using aligned and unaligned loads

```
float x[4], y[4]
__m128 x4 = _mm_loadu_ps(x);
__m128 y4 = _mm_sqrt_ps(x4);
_mm_storeu_ps(y,y4);
```

This gives (with Intel syntax)

```
movups  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx]
sqrtps  xmm0, xmm0
```

However, if we do an aligned load we get the other form

```
float x[4], y[4]
__m128 x4 = _mm_load_ps(x);
__m128 y4 = _mm_sqrt_ps(x4);
_mm_storeu_ps(y,y4);
```

This combines the load and square root into one instruction

```
sqrtps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
```

Most people would say "trust the compiler." I disagree. If you're using intrinsics then it should be assumed that YOU know what you're doing and NOT the compiler.  Here is an example [difference-in-performance-between-msvc-and-gcc-for-highly-optimized-matrix-multp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134279/difference-in-performance-between-msvc-and-gcc-for-highly-optimized-matrix-multp) where GCC chose one form and MSVC chose the other form (for multiplication instead of the sqrt) and it made a difference in performance.

So once again, if you're using aligned loads, you can only pray that the compiler does what you want.  And then maybe on the next version of the compiler it does something different...

Answer (score 2):

Quick research: I made the following file, called `mysqrt.cpp`:

```
#include <pmmintrin.h>

extern "C" __m128 MySqrt(__m128* a) {
    return _mm_sqrt_ps(a[1]);
}
```

Trying gcc, namely `g++4.8 -msse3 -O3 -S mysqrt.cpp && cat mysqrt.s`:

```
_MySqrt:
LFB526:
    sqrtps  16(%rdi), %xmm0
    ret
```

Clang (`clang++3.6 -msse3 -O3 -S mysqrt.cpp && cat mysqrt.s`):

```
_MySqrt:                                ## @MySqrt
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:                                ## %entry
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    sqrtps  16(%rdi), %xmm0
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

Don't know about VS, but at least both gcc and clang seem to produce memory version of `sqrtps` if needed.

**UPDATE** Example of function usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pmmintrin.h>

extern "C" __m128 MySqrt(__m128* a);

int main() {
    __m128 x[2];
    x[1] = _mm_set_ps1(4);
    __m128 y = MySqrt(x);
    std::cout << y[0] << std::endl;
}

// output:
2
```

**UPDATE 2:** Regarding your code, you should just do:

```
auto xmm = _mm_sqrt_ps(*reinterpret_cast<__m128*>(data));
```

And of course it will be at your own risk, you should guarantee that `data` contains valid `__m128` and is properly aligned.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayeb3ayc.aspx `You should not access the __m128 fields directly.` What are you doing here `_mm_sqrt_ps(a[1]);` ?

Comment: `a` is a pointer to array of `__m128`s, `a[1]` is the second element of an array. This is to emphasize that its value is taken from memory.

Comment: And what about `You should not access the __m128 fields directly` ?

Comment: @tower120 I don't do it, where do you see it? Again, `a[1]` is `__m128`, not a field of `__m128`.

Comment: `_mm_sqrt_ps(a[1])` - you access `*a` of type **__m128** with offset.

Comment: @tower120 No. I access the second element of `__m128[]` array. Anyway, you can replace `a[1]` with `*a` in the code, it will produce memory version anyway.

Comment: Ok. Than show me work example with this. How do you fill __m128 *a?

Comment: @tower120 OK, see the update. I access the fields of result for output, but it's not related to MySqrt function

Comment: But you first move all your data to xmm register with _mm_set_ps1. Look here http://goo.gl/MeBCq5 you fill xmm0 with sequence of commands.  Than you do `sqrtps %xmm0, %xmm0` !!! REGISTER TO REGISTER. There is another version of sqrtps, REGISTER TO MEMORY. http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_299.html SQRTPS xmm1, m128. You can directly work with aligned memory block float[4].

Comment: @tower120 look at assembly code I provided in my answer, where do you see `sqrtps %xmm0, %xmm0`? Also, if you read carefully the doc, there's no "register to memory" version of sqrtps, only "memory to register" and "register to register".

Comment: @tower120 Edit your question and provide example of a real code, what assembly code you get and what you expect to be a better code.

Comment: @tower120 you see `sqrtps %xmm0, %xmm0` in the link you provided because the compiler inlined `MySqrt` function, to prevent inlining you should use two cpp files.

Comment: And what is valid `__m128 `? I don't see structure of it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayeb3ayc.aspx

Comment: @tower120 __m128 is essentially `float[4]` array, properly aligned. Also, imagine you had `_mm_sqrt_ps(float*)` function - the requirements for it would be the same.

Comment: "__m128 is essentially float[4] array, properly aligned." - where you read this? I didn't found this on msdn.

Comment: @tower120 in the file `xmmintrin.h`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the interface provided by the primitive `_mm_sqrt_ps(__m128)`. The argument type here can be a variable hold in memory or in register. The extension type `__m128` acts like any normal builtin type, e.g. `double`, and is not bound to an xmm register but can also be stored in memory.

**EDIT** Unless you use `asm`, the compiler determines if and when a variable is loaded into register or left in memory. So, in the following code snippet

```
__m128 foo(const __m128 x, const __m128*y, std::size_t n)
{
  __m128 result = _mm_set_ps(1.0);
  while(n--)
    result = _mm_mul_ps(result,_mm_add_ps(x,_mm_sqrt_ps(*y++)));
  return result;
}
```

it's up to the compiler which variables are stored in register. I would think that the compiler puts `x` and `result` into xmm registers, but gets `*y` directly from memory.

Comment: You still don't understand what `__m128` means. I tried to explain further in the edited question.

Comment: Shouldn't you `_mm_load_ps` before work further with data? Before `std::cout` it, for example?

Comment: Because, as I understand, only sse instructions can work with xmm registers.

Comment: You still don't understand. **`__m128` is a type**, not a register (nor is this type guaranteed to 'live' in an xmm register). I don't think that `operator(std::ostream&, __m128)` is defined anywhere, but you can define it for yourself. This definition will need access to the individual elements of an `__m128`, for which there exists no portable interface. In order to get hold of these elements, you could use `_mm_load_ps()`, though with clang you can simply call `__m128 a; a[0];` and with gcc you can use `__builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v4sf(a,0)`.