# accessing __m128 fields across compilers

Tags: visual-c++, g++, sse, icc

I've noticed that accessing `__m128` fields by index is possible in `gcc`, without using the `union` trick.

```
__m128 t;

float r(t[0] + t[1] + t[2] + t[3]);
```

I can also load a `__m128` just like an array:

```
__m128 t{1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f};
```

This is all in line with `gcc`'s vector extensions. These, however, may not be available elsewhere. Are the loading and accessing features supported by the intel compiler and msvc?

Comment: Standard C++ does not support SSE. Which target platforms are you interested in?

Comment: What is the `union` trick for accessing the fields of __m128?

Comment: @Blue something like: `union vec { __m128 a; float b[4]; double c[2]; };`. It's not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load a `__m128`, you can write `_mm_setr_ps(1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f)`, which is supported by GCC, ICC, MSVC and clang.

So far as I know, clang and recent versions of GCC support accessing `__m128` fields by index. I don't know how to do this in ICC or MSVC. I guess `_mm_extract_ps` works for all 4 compilers but its return type is insane making it painful to use.

Comment: You don't want `_mm_extract_ps` for this because a scalar float is just the low element of an XMM register.  You want to shuffle the float you want to the bottom of a vector (e.g. with `_mm_shuffle_ps` or `_mm_insert_ps`), for `_mm_cvtps_f32` (which is just a cast, no asm instructions).  You don't want the compiler to emit an `extractps` instruction unless the destination is memory; it's basically just `pextrd`.  (  [Intel SSE: Why does \`\_mm\_extract\_ps\` return \`int\` instead of \`float\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41191977))

Comment: @PeterCordes Contemporary compilers don't interpret `_mm_extract_ps` as a command to generate *exactly* the extractps instruction, but instead "extract an element using whatever instruction the compiler thinks is best".  GCC may generate nothing, movshdup, movhlps, shufps, extractps, or pextrd for `_mm_extract_ps`, depending on the index and context.

Comment: MSVC doesn't optimize intrinsics, and *does* use what you asked for.  I think ICC is the same.  Clang's shuffle optimizer is good, and GCC may or may not figure this out if you type-pun it back to float with `memcpy` or a union or `std::bit_cast`, but it's super inconvenient and leading the compiler in the direction of bad asm.

Answer (score 3):

If you want you code to work on other compilers then don't use those GCC extensions.  Use the set/load/store intrinsics.  `_mm_setr_ps` is fine for setting constant values but should not be used in a loop.  To access elements I normally store the values to an array first then read the array.

If you have an array `a` you should read/store it in with

```
__m128 t = _mm_loadu_ps(a);
_mm_storeu_ps(a, t);
```

If the array is 16-byte aligned you can use an aligned load/store which is slightly faster on newer systems but much faster on older systems.

```
__m128 t = _mm_load_ps(a);
_mm_store_ps(a, t);
```

To get 16-byte aligned memory on the stack use

```
__declspec(align(16)) const float a[] = ...//MSVC
__attribute__((aligned(16))) const float a[] ...//GCC, ICC
```

For 16-byte aligned [dynamic arrays use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376942/best-cross-platform-method-to-get-aligned-memory):

```
float *a = (float*)_mm_malloc(sizeof(float)*n, 16); //MSVC, GCC, ICC, MinGW
```

Comment: I like addressing by index, as this allows me not to do those pesky shifts. What about the shifts?

Comment: Shifts?  You store to an array and access the array by index like any array.

Comment: Ahh, now I see what you mean... From disassembly I've seen that the compiler does some shifting of the xmm registers to implement the index addressing.

Comment: Well you can't have it both ways in this case.  Don't expect those GCC extensions to go into MSVC.  Those extensions can also lead to non-optimal code if you're not careful.  Particularly if you treat the SIMD registers like an array and insert/read one or two elements of the register in a loop.  The extensions make this so easy, too easy...

Comment: Well, one doesn't need to think of extensions as being particular to `gcc`, these extensions have made it (perhaps partially, I don't have `icc`) into `icc`. They also wouldn't need to get into MSVC in their entirety.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use macros for this:

```
//Test to see if we are using MSVC as MSVC AVX types are slightly different to the GCC ones
#ifdef _MSC_VER 
#define GET_F32_AVX_MULTIPLATTFORM(vector,index) (vector).m256_f32[index]
#define GET_F64_AVX_MULTIPLATTFORM(vector,index) (vector).m256d_f64[index]
#else 
#define GET_F32_AVX_MULTIPLATTFORM(vector,index) (vector)[index]
#define GET_F64_AVX_MULTIPLATTFORM(vector,index) (vector)[index]
#endif
```