# Access value from __m128 in rust by index

Tags: rust, simd, sse2

I have seen that it's rather simple in C to access values in a `__m128` register by index. However, it is not possible to do that in rust. How can I access those values?

Concretely, I am calculating four values at once, then I compare them using `_mm_cmplt_ps`. I use that return register as a mask for further computation.

Answer (score 2):

There are SIMD instructions precisely for this, e.g. such as [`_mm_extract_epi32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/arch/x86_64/fn._mm_extract_epi32.html), but they often require newer versions of SIMD than just SSE2.

I think the easiest way to do this using foolproof safe Rust is using the [`bytemuck`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/) crate, in your example:

```
let cmp = _mm_cmplt_ps(a, b);
let cmp_arr: [u32; 4] = bytemuck::cast(cmp);
```

Now `cmp_arr[0]`, `cmp_arr[1]`, ..., contain your results.

Comment: Presumably would compile to the same asm as C++ `std::bit_cast` to an array.  For an `__m128` (float vector) example of how that compiles, see [Why can't Clang get \_\_m128's data by index in constexpr function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73087452) which coincidentally was also asked in the last day.  (An FP compare result is appropriate to extract as `u32`, typically into an integer register, not still FP.  So this case is a little different).  Also note that `_mm_extract_epi32` requires a compile-time-constant index, because `pextrd` needs an immediate operand.