# free() hangs when passed a valid pointer created by posix_memalign() - gcc and C++11

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, posix, free

I need to allocate 16-byte-aligned memory, and from what I can tell the accepted method to do so is `posix_memalign()`, using the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html) as reference (other StackOverflow questions indicated this to be so). The code below is simplified to exclude unrelated parts (ie other platforms), but I have kept some context (sse is just a namespace):

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
float* sse::alloc(unsigned int count)
{
    void* p;
    int r = posix_memalign(&p,16,sizeof(float)*count);
    if ( r == 0 )
        return (float*)p;
    /* else output error and exit(1) - has never failed */
    else exit(1);
}

void sse::free(float* p)
{
    free(p);
}
```

The code that uses it is pretty self-explanatory:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const unsigned int total = 16000;
    float *array = sse::alloc(total), *arr2 = sse::alloc(total);
    /* null ptr checks */
    // ...
    sse::free(array); sse::free(arr2);
    return 0;
}
```

I have commented out all non-essential code to test this, and have confirmed that it does indeed 'hang' on `free(p);` - when I <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> in gdb it reports the line. The behaviour is no different in valgrind, and the SSE code (using Intel intrinsics) (in place of `...`) runs successfully. I have been compiling with fairly standard options: `-g -O3 -std=c++11`, and have tried no/less optimisation, no debug, and some unnecessary casts. Some information about my system (please ask if you would like more):

- uname -a: Linux (name) 3.12.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT (date) x86_64 GNU/Linux
- g++ --version: 4.8.2
- gdb --version: 7.6.1
- valgrind --version: 3.9.0

Since the man pages clearly state that `free()` is the correct function, I am incredibly stumped, and I would prefer to avoid writing a mechanism to use new/delete and padding by 15 bytes (for obvious reasons). If there is an alternative that I am unaware of, I am happy to try that. Also, information about potential causes of such a hang could prove useful, as it is particularly difficult to search for some of these terms (still easier than searching for 'stack overflow').

Comment: Can you post the minimal code? Your example code is missing the return from `alloc`, among other things.

Comment: Edited to include enough for it to compile.

Comment: @Neofish: But there's no `main`, so it does nothing. Post your [testcase](http://sscce.org). If you don't have one yet, you need to do more debugging on your own before resorting to asking here.

Comment: (Though it would appear that you have stumbled upon a genuine mystery, so I'd be interested in the answer, when we get there.)

Comment: Use _mm_malloc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376942/best-cross-platform-method-to-get-aligned-memory

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need to call the global free - change the free routine to:

```
void sse::free(float* p)
{
    ::free(p);
}
```

namespace rules cause it to call `sse::free` unless otherwise told

Comment: Ouch, that has to sting.

Comment: Omg I can't believe I missed that.. I'm so ashamed. Thanks.

Comment: @Neofish If you'd compiled *without* optimizations, the stack overflow would have been more evident; however, the compiler decided to helpfully "optimize" the infinite recursion into an infinite loop instead.

Comment: @Adam Useful to know, although it seems to make that optimisation anyway (might be my CFLAGS/etc). Can readily make it overflow by changing to a pointer-reference, or better, a C-style cast to void* raises a compile-time type error, which would make it a bit more clear.