# Segmentation fault with array of __m256i when using clang/g++

Tags: c++, clang, avx, icc

I'm attempting to generate arrays of `__m256i`'s to reuse in another computation. When I attempt to do that (even with a minimal testcase), I get a segmentation fault - but only if the code is compiled with g++ or clang. If I compile the code with the Intel compiler (version 16.0), no segmentation fault occurs. Here is a test case I created:

```
int main() {
    __m256i *table = new __m256i[10000];
    __m256i zeroes = _mm256_set_epi64x(0, 0, 0, 0);
    table[99] = zeroes;
}
```

When compiling the above with clang 3.6 and g++ 4.8, a segmentation fault occurs.

Here's the assembly generated by the Intel compiler (from https://gcc.godbolt.org/, icc 13.0):

```
pushq     %rbx                                          #3.12
movq      %rsp, %rbx                                    #3.12
andq      $-32, %rsp                                    #3.12
pushq     %rbp                                          #3.12
pushq     %rbp                                          #3.12
movq      8(%rbx), %rbp                                 #3.12
movq      %rbp, 8(%rsp)                                 #3.12
movq      %rsp, %rbp                                    #3.12
subq      $112, %rsp                                    #3.12
movl      $3200, %eax                                   #4.38
vzeroupper                                              #4.38
movq      %rax, %rdi                                    #4.38
call      operator new[](unsigned long)                 #4.38
movq      %rax, -112(%rbp)                              #4.38
movq      -112(%rbp), %rax                              #4.38
movq      %rax, -104(%rbp)                              #4.20
vxorps    %ymm0, %ymm0, %ymm0                           #5.22
vmovdqu   %ymm0, -80(%rbp)                              #5.22
vmovdqu   -80(%rbp), %ymm0                              #5.22
vmovdqu   %ymm0, -48(%rbp)                              #5.20
movl      $3168, %eax                                   #6.17
addq      -104(%rbp), %rax                              #6.5
vmovdqu   -48(%rbp), %ymm0                              #6.17
vmovdqu   %ymm0, (%rax)                                 #6.5
movl      $0, %eax                                      #7.1
vzeroupper                                              #7.1
leave                                                   #7.1
movq      %rbx, %rsp                                    #7.1
popq      %rbx                                          #7.1
ret                                                     #7.1
```

And here's from clang 3.7:

```
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp
andq    $-32, %rsp
subq    $192, %rsp
xorl    %eax, %eax
movl    $3200, %ecx             # imm = 0xC80
movl    %ecx, %edi
movl    %eax, 28(%rsp)          # 4-byte Spill
callq   operator new[](unsigned long)
movq    %rax, 88(%rsp)
movq    $0, 168(%rsp)
movq    $0, 160(%rsp)
movq    $0, 152(%rsp)
movq    $0, 144(%rsp)
vmovq   168(%rsp), %xmm0        # xmm0 = mem[0],zero
vmovq   160(%rsp), %xmm1        # xmm1 = mem[0],zero
vpunpcklqdq     %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm0 # xmm0 = xmm1[0],xmm0[0]
vmovq   152(%rsp), %xmm1        # xmm1 = mem[0],zero
vpslldq $8, %xmm1, %xmm1        # xmm1 = zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,xmm1[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
vmovaps %xmm1, %xmm2
vinserti128     $1, %xmm0, %ymm2, %ymm2
vmovaps %ymm2, 96(%rsp)
vmovaps %ymm2, 32(%rsp)
movq    88(%rsp), %rax
vmovaps %ymm2, 3168(%rax)
movl    28(%rsp), %eax          # 4-byte Reload
movq    %rbp, %rsp
popq    %rbp
vzeroupper
retq
```

Am I running into a compiler bug in clang/g++? Or am I simply doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you see which line causes the segmentation fault?

Comment: @Paulo It's the last line - `table[99] = zeroes`.

Comment: Unrelated note: I believe `_mm256_set1_epi64x(0)` would be the same as `_mm256_set_epi64x(0, 0, 0, 0)`.

Comment: 4.8 is rather old. How does it look with 4.9.3 or 5.2?

Comment: @SergeyA No segmentation fault with 5.3. So... I guess it is a compiler bug?

Comment: @hichris123, looks like it.

Comment: Strange @SergeyA - I think that may have been a fluke. If I bump the array size up to 10,000 or higher, I still get a segmentation fault - even in gcc 5.3. Perhaps something changed with my system, because even the earlier versions of clang/gcc now produce no segmentation faults with the code in the post.

Comment: It is a well known issue that malloc/new can't handle overaligned types in C++. People are working on it for a future version of the standard...

Comment: @R_Kapp: The normal thing would be `_mm256_setzero_si256()`.  Modern compilers are smart enough to still compile `set1(0)` or `set(0,0,0,0)` to a `VPXOR xmm,xmm` instruction, though.  (non-zero constants tend to turn into a load from the .rodata section, except all-ones which can be generated by `PCMPEQB same,same`).

Comment: Also, if you're going to post asm output, use `-Og` or `-O1` at least, unless it's a problem that only happens with `-O0`.  Nobody wants to read the braindead `-O0` output that buries the interesting part under stuff like 4x `movq $0, (stack)`.  And if you have the code on godbolt, click the "permalink" button and post that link to take people to the code on godbolt with your chosen compiler and options.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, I probably should have done `O1`+, but I realized the compiler would optimize the good stuff right out. I'll make sure to do that next time.

Comment: @hichris123: You'd still get an aligned store.  What "good stuff" are you referring to?  Oh right, you don't use `table`, and it's newly allocated so the compiler knows it has the only reference to it.  So it goes away with `-O1`, [but not with `-Og`](http://goo.gl/xLQGrB).

Answer (score 3):

I guess the problem has to do with wrong memory alignment. `vmovaps` requires the memory location to start at a 32-byte boundary and `vmovdqu` does not. That's why the Intel version works whereas the clang/g++ code crashes. I don't know if this is a compiler bug, but you may want alignment anyway.

The following code should work, although it's more C than C++.

```
int main() {
  __m256i *table = (__m256i*) memalign( 32, 10000 * sizeof(__m256i) );
  __m256i zeroes = _mm256_set_epi64x(0, 0, 0, 0);
  table[99] = zeroes;
}
```

Comment: This does indeed work. As you point out though, it's more of a C implementation than a C++ fix.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_mm256_store_epi32&expand=5573,5567,5567,5567&ig_expand=7083) is a link to the relevant part of the intrinsics guide that states that the target location must be aligned on a 32-byte boundary.

Answer (score 3):

I have said many times before that implicit SIMD loads/stores are a bad idea. Stop using them. Use explicit loads/stores like this

```
int64_t* table = new int64_t[4*10000];
__m256i zeroes = _mm256_set_epi64x(0, 0, 0, 0);
_mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&table[4*99], zeroes);
```

or since this is POD use [the cross-compiler/OS function `_mm_malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376942/best-cross-platform-method-to-get-aligned-memory)

```
int64_t* table = (int64_t*)_mm_malloc(sizeof(int64_t)*4*10000, 32);
__m256i zeroes = _mm256_set_epi64x(0, 0, 0, 0);
_mm256_store_si256((__m256i*)&table[4*99], zeroes);
```

You can use `_mm256_setzero_si256()` instead of `_mm256_set_epi64x(0, 0, 0, 0)` (note that `_mm256_set_epi64x` does not work in 32-bit mode on some version of MSVC) but GCC and Clang are smart enough to know they are the same thing.

Since you're using intrinsics which are not part of the C/C++ specification [then some rules such as strict aliasing may be overlooked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787268/how-to-implement-mm-storeu-epi64-without-aliasing-problems/24788226#24788226).