# How to allocate 4k aligned Memory

Tags: linux, memory-management, malloc

`malloc()` allocates a memory chunk which is virtually contiguous inside the process memory space. `malloc()` takes a size as a parameter in bytes and returns pointer to that allocated memory space but what if the requirement is to allocate memory which is 4k aligned?

Comment: You probably mean `aligned` not `aliened`

Comment: Maybe you should [read this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227897/solve-the-memory-alignment-in-c-interview-question-that-stumped-me/227900#227900) which is about a very similar problem, although for general (not Linux specific) domain.

Answer (score 3):

That would almost certainly be achieved using something like [posix_memalign](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_memalign).

Comment: If you can provide a simple example shows how to use it to get 4k aligned, that will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since 4Kbytes is often the size of a page (see [sysconf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html) with `_SC_PAGESIZE` or the old [getpagesize(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpagesize.2.html) syscall) you could use [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) syscall (which is used by `malloc` and `posix_memalign`) to get 4Kaligned memory.

Comment: Note that if you use `mmap()` directly you may find yourself with less memory available.  In the most pessimal case, allocating 4 KiB blocks from `mmap()` gives a maximum of 256 MiB total memory allocated, since there is a 2^16 limit on number of `mmap()` regions.

Answer (score 0):

you can not allocate physically contiguous memory in user space. Because in User space kernel always allocates memory from highmem zone. But if you are writing a kernel module or a system space code then you can use _get_page() or _get_pages().

Comment: The  function  posix_memalign()  allocates size bytes and places the address of the allocated memory in *memptr.  The address of the allocated memory will be a multiple of alignment, which must be a power of two and a multiple of sizeof(void *).  If size is 0, then the value placed  in  *memptr  is either NULL, or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to free(3).