# Understand the code to adjust buffer

Tags: c

Could anyone explain the following code to me?

```
adjustedbuf = (void *) ((uint64_t) buf & ~(pagesize - 1))
```

I don't get the idea of this statement.

Comment: I think it's page-aligning the buffer with bit ops

Comment: It *is* some sort of "alignment". It might be helpful if you provides some context, the platform, and the value of `pagesize`.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `pagesize` is a power of two, its binary representation will be something like:

```
  0000 10000000  // assume page size = 2^7 = 128
```

So `pagesize-1` will be:

```
  0000 01111111  // 127
```

The negation of that (`~`) will be a bitmask, with all upper bits set, up to the "page size" bit:

```
  1111 10000000
```

If you `&` that with anything, you end up with a number that is "rounded down" to a multiple of the page size

```
  1100 10110110
& 1111 10000000
= 1100 10000000
```

Which is what that statement is doing. It aligns `buf` to a page size boundary.

<sub>(If `pagesize` isn't a power of two, the whole thing doesn't make much sense.)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

It's page-aligning the buffer using bit operations. See

[How to allocate aligned memory only using the standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227897/solve-the-memory-alignment-in-c-interview-question-that-stumped-me)

for more depth.