# What's the purpose of page-aligned allocation?

Tags: c, malloc

I'm looking at come C code which seems to be allocating memory aligned to the page size:

`_aligned_malloc( size, PAGESIZE )`

where `PAGESIZE` is a variable set to 4096. For the moment ignoring that page size could have a value different from 4096, I just want to know why one would want to align the memory allocation to the page size. What performance benefits does it provide, if any? Could it have any other purpose than performance?

Comment: Shared memory prefers whole pages. Also changing the protection on a block of memory usually involves whole pages.

Comment: It might be a good idea to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088732/explanation-to-aligned-malloc-implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be related to [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging), and to [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). Page size is related to the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) so is usually constrained by the hardware.

On some operating systems, some functions or [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) want (i.e. require) a page-aligned pointer. For example, on Linux, [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (notably when you use it with `MAP_FIXED`, it wants a genuine page aligned address), [mprotect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html), [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html), [mlock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html), [mremap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html), also related [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html).

Some very low-level IO operations might prefer (e.g. run faster) with page aligned buffers (perhaps [send(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html), or direct [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) to some block device...) because the kernel might avoid some block copy (e.g. do some [DMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access)) and could special-case page aligned data.