# Allocating memory for __m256i

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, x86, avx

I've encountered such a mysterious Segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
struct Box{
    __m256i L;
};
int main()
{
    struct Box *result=NULL;
    result=(struct Box *)malloc(sizeof(struct Box));
    (*result).L=(*result).L;
}
```

Compiled with flags `-msse4.2 -march=corei7-avx`

It runs totally fine on my Mac (OS X EI Caption 10.11.6, GCC 4.8.4).
But it gives me Segmentation fault on Amazon EC2 machine (Ubuntu 14.04, GCC 4.8.4).

When I make a slight change:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
struct Box{
    __m256i L;
};
int main()
{
    struct Box result[1];
    (*result).L=(*result).L;
}
```

It will be able to run on the Ubuntu machine.

Does anyone have any explanation about this?

Comment: malloc doesn't guarantee 32B-aligned memory.

Answer (score 4):

### Alignment, Malloc Behavior, and Stack allocations

@Peter Cordes's comment addresses part of the problem.

Specifically on your OSX machine you are "always" getting correctly aligned memory which meets the alignment needs for the assembly generated for the `__m256i` datatype, which is [supposed to be 32 byte aligned](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524040). (I put "always" in quotations because it isn't guaranteed with `malloc`.  You may have just gotten lucky with OSX's `malloc`.  Multiple runs of the same code tend to get the same alignments, unlike repeated calls to `malloc` inside one program.  Actually, see below: the compiler on OS X generates different asm)

On Ubuntu, you are not getting a suitable alignment in the memory address returned by `malloc`. (See below for details on why.)

You call your second code snippet a `slight change`.

```
int main()
{
    struct Box result[1];
    (*result).L=(*result).L;
}
```

It is actually quite substantially different from the first snippet which uses `malloc` because the the complier (gcc here) is aware of the alignment requirements of the data type `Box` (and by extension `__m256i` also) when allocating the memory on the stack. Thus there is no risk of segfaulting in this case because the complier provides the correct alignment.

You can manipulate the base pointer returned by `malloc` as explained in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/227900/3516034. I'll let you look there for the details but in short you can do something like

```
struct Box *result=NULL;
void *mem = malloc(2 * sizeof(struct Box));
result = (struct Box *)((uintptr_t)mem + offset);
```

where `offset` allows you to explore the alignment and segfaults. It may be useful for you to print out the pointer address you end up using for `result` like `printf("0x%08" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)result);` (again from that post).

### Instruction Differences

Lastly, I can reproduce this on Ubuntu and OSX. I actually see my OSX `malloc` calls giving *16 byte* alignment and not 32 byte alignment. I *also* see 16 byte alignment on Ubuntu (in a VM on the same hardware) which *is* causing the segfault. When I manually align to 32 bytes, the segfault goes away.

So the root cause of your problem is that the systems are not generating the same assembly instructions.  I got the assembly with the `-S` option to gcc.  On OSX, I see `vmovaps` used 4 times with XMM operands, and on Ubuntu `vmovdqa` twice with YMM operands, to move a `__m256i`.

[`vmovdqa`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVDQA.html) and [`vmovaps`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVAPS.html) require their memory operands to be naturally-aligned (i.e. 32B for YMM, 16B for XMM).  So the assembly generated on OSX only requires 16B alignment even though `__m256i` is 32B.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the code ALWAYS run properly on my Mac. It looks like  this is contradict your theory. According to your theory, It should also give a Segfault since it gives 16 byte alignment but not 32 byte alignment.

Comment: It is more complicated than that. As I explain in the "instruction differences" section, gcc on your OSX is generating assembly instructions that only require _16 byte_ alignment _even though the C datatype `__m256i` requires 32 byte alignment. This is why it is working on your Mac - the resulting binary only needs 16 byte alignment, not 32 byte. The Ubuntu build generates instructions that require 32 byte alignment.

Comment: That explains everything. Thanks!